# What was the profile for the main character of the April 2016 joke?

Tags: discussion, april-fools, unikong

April 2016's joke for SE was a game and there was an account with the same name as it.

What was the profile URL of that account?

Comment: Ummm.... The account was imaginary, not a real account. The game did refer to [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/Jon-Skeet), however the game did not change his rep. (probably wouldn't make much of a difference anyway, considering he has 862k on SO)

Comment: What makes you think it was "tied to account"?? Nothing in the game indicates this. Maybe you forgot, you can [play it here](http://stackexchange.github.io/unikong/), and if you find anything to support your claim, please take a screenshot and post it here as well.

Comment: @ShadowWizard As in tied, I meant related.

Comment: You mean Jon Skeet account? If not, what account? Really can't see what you mean here.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, In the first comment someone answered. So yes. I am waiting for them to make an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 'person' you play in the game is [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/Jon-Skeet). He is well known as the highest reputation user on StackOverflow, with a total rep of > 1 million ([official blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/01/15/thanks-million-jon-skeet/)). As such he has become one of the [biggest memes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/66838#66838) on SE, even becoming the [Chuck Norris of programming](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts).

See, he was thanked in the credits:

[image: Special thanks: Jon Skeet]

Note that the game is not 'linked' to his account - Jon Skeet gains no rep from Unikong. (It probably wouldn't matter anyway - he hits the daily rep cap constantly without even trying, so this would make no difference.)

Comment: I think you can edit the question with > 1m :)