# Winter Bash 2018 Knitting

Tags: discussion, fun, winter-bash, winter-bash-2018

> **NOTE**: for this year, there's a new topic: [Winter Bash 2019 Knitting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339896/295232)

This year's Winter Bash got us great hat challenges, but it also gave us a very nice tool for knitting on the [main Winter Bash site](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/).

Is there a challenge related to this knitting tool?

Here is my knitting and it would be amazing if you could share yours too.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for creating this question. It gave me more incentive for fun. :-)

Comment: Looks like they intended this to become the annual rep fest.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Well, it _could_ be a great way to unlock some hats that require putting a bit of effort into writing (or, well, knitting in this case) an answer. Opportunities don't always present themselves throughout the network, so .... I kinda like this question :)

Comment: @TimPost that is true. Guess no chance for actual swag for top answers? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard There ... might be something in the works. I can not confirm nor deny any things for any things. But there might be things, or other things. But the thing is, the things are the way they are because of other things, so we'll just have to thing positively and see.

Comment: Clear as mud, Mr Post. Clear as Mud ;p

Comment: What's with the shape of the knitting canvas?

Comment: @j08691 [good question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320008/what-is-the-shape-of-the-knitting-canvas)! ;-)

Comment: damn, people are good with a mouse... I was happy with my motorcycle helmet but now it just feels inadequate https://imgur.com/a/6qZmBUi

Comment: Thank you for this. My exemplary knitting ability has earned me a privilege.

Comment: Lol, through this, I designed a StackOverflow Character lololololol the ideas people get

Comment: @Rob You're welcome. Continue to post such answers as a part of other contests too. Please try to stay active on meta after WB also.

Comment: @NogShine - I've put up a couple more animated knitting answers, what we really need for next time is some more colors and vertical resolution. The ability to upload .gifs to the *knitting machine* would sure save a lot of effort, my last entry is **70** frames. I lurk in The Tavern and am quite active in CHQ.

Comment: This is a fun question!

Comment: @rob someone actually did an userscript for adding more colors to the ui, but I think that still has the issue that the underlying logic doesn't really take those color in consideration. I expect that importing a picture with more colors than the original ones wouldn't produce the expected result.

Comment: @Eran this is a waffle question!

Comment: @SPArchaeologist also a Freehand Circle question

Comment: @SPArchaeologist - It is ArtOfCode's script, not sure that the *knitting machine* would accept it without substituting it's own choice of colors. Also I did no *cheating* the image posted is as-received from the server, frame by frame concatenated together.

Comment: @rob I was talking about your "what we really need for next time is some more colors and vertical resolution" line, meaning that someone tried to fix the "too few colors" problem manually but didn't get a perfect result. Basically, I agree with you - we need built-in increased color palette next time.

Comment: and .GIF uploading that doesn't think that a multiple frame .gif had only the first frame. :)

Comment: @NogShine - I've written a complete tutorial as an answer to a question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/320848/282094

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Knitting the logos! Can you guess them all??? :D

[image: Stack Exchange site logos in the Sweater Builder with the text I heart the Stack Exchange Network]

Older versions are saved in the image links list (edit to see them).

Comment: Since you forgot Movies & TV, I [knitted it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319942/321725) for ya. ;-P

Comment: @AJ Just had to think about how to implement it. :D

Comment: Wow! You knitted 37 sites! I see a little more space there. :D

Comment: rpg.se has some questions....

Comment: @goodguy5: Glad I wasn't the only one to immediately look for it... :)

Comment: @goodguy5 If you can get the RPG logo in a 9x9 square, I'll be happy to add it. :D It was beyond my sad abilities of digital knitting.

Comment: @Catija Welp, I spent about 30 minutes of work's time trying to figure it out. I think you're right. can't be done. I even tried zooming in to cut off the "border". I tried just the "twenty" side.

Comment: @goodguy5: [My condolences.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXsqA.png) ;)

Comment: Just...whoa. How do people make these??

Comment: @Eleeza time, patience, and freehand skills developed in MS Paint

Comment: ... in my case, I think it mostly comes from a childhood doing cross stitch and crochet. I'm not actually a knitter.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I use Paint too because my drawing tablet is broken

Comment: Great effort with all the sites!

Comment: That's impressive!.

Comment: Looks like there's room for *one* more over on the bottom left.  Who will it be? :-)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Found room for SF and SA and some text.

Comment: So will you be knitting those new SE swag sweaters then?

Comment: Missed that you added movies later, so +1

Answer (score 86):

What better to draw in the winter bash header then a scene from a winter bash header!

[image: my drawing the 2015 winter bash header art]

Here is the header from 2015 for reference:
[image: the real 2015 winter bash header]

Comment: I like the realism. :-)

Comment: Very nice, but you skipped the trees :)

Comment: If they hadn't ~you would not be able to see the wood for the trees~ oh dear, the trees were removed to build the houses, not a particular good thing so I'd suggest supporting [Sustainable-Living SE](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/33364/sustainable-living) ...!

Answer (score 82):

Winter Bash Invaders

[image: Winter Bash Invaders]

OK, you guys wanted one with hats...

[image: Winter Bash Invaders Redux]

Comment: Now do one where the invaders are _hats!_

Comment: On no!! Protect the hats at all cost!!

Comment: Maybe the shooter could be a hat.

Comment: I loved that game

Comment: @DennisWilliamson - Done.

Comment: Beautiful! `<tears />`

Comment: Don't shoot at Brunhilde!  Do you *want* a charging horde of warriors on your doorstep?

Comment: How often does the *mystery roast turkey* fly across the top of the screen?

Answer (score 79):

### No-one has knitted an ugly christmas sweater yet?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Someone mentioned unicorns. Full credit for the idea of using unicorns instead of deer goes to [Catija](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/284336/catija)

Comment: That is proper ugly

Comment: I think it's lovely, I would wear that design. Is there something wrong with me???

Comment: This is *so* good!

Comment: This looks great. Also reminds me of a similar sweater I had during my childhood.

Comment: Ridiculously ugly sweater!

Comment: That's very pretty!

Comment: For some reason, these patterns remind me of some Animal Crossing shirts.

Comment: @Eran (and others leaving comments saying this is good/ great)... it's supposed to be ugly... Care to explain where I went wrong? ;)

Comment: Unicorns, excellent!

Answer (score 73):

[image: A knitted beach scene with the title "Summer Bash 2018"]

Comment: Could be awesome if Konami caused this to appear instead of the current logo, but guess it's too late to add now. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard can be an idea for next year at least. Also, missing chickens.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist I guess chicken was a one time thing. But on the other hand, balpha told us [to stop guessing](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=7429575#7429575) so there's still hope! ;)

Answer (score 72):

Help I can't get mine to run!

[image: Winter Bash Knitting]

**EDIT:** I just couldn't unpick the Wool Reference Exception I was getting, so on **schohe001**'s excellent suggestion, here is winterba.sh too :)

[image]

Comment: Missed the opportunity to write "Winter" in the language Bash :P Still love the idea though!

Comment: Ha! That would have been much better, I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader ;)

Comment: We could call it Code Bash!

Comment: Looks like Winter is not *coming* but is already here!

Comment: No, no! It's `winter.bash`!

Answer (score 71):

## Na na na na na na na na na na na na na na

[image: Bat symbol]

## BATMAN!

Comment: As usual... your submissions to contests are always superb. This is kinda a contest... ish...

Comment: Don't you mean Hatman?

Comment: How about Knitman?

Answer (score 68):

Bugs Bunny - [Hillbilly Hare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hillbilly_Hare)

[image: Hillbilly Hare]

Comment: Knitting is a “manual” thing, you people are taking this to the next level

Comment: +1 for being animated

Comment: Thanks. I did this on my phone without webhacks or custom scripts. It's 24 FPS and only 1MB. I suspect that we might see something better in the near future.

Comment: Aww, beat me to an animation. I'll have to post mine later.

Comment: +1 for sheer effort.

Comment: @hat - Thanks, my newest answer is **70** frames - they look better if you stand back a bit - https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/320375/282094

Comment: Very impressive

Comment: I've posted tutorial, see the link in a comment to the question.

Comment: This answer received honorable mention on the Stack Overflow Blog: "[Adios to Winter Bash 2018 , by Juan M (Jan 4 2019)](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/01/04/adios-to-winter-bash-2018/)" in the section: "fabulous sweater designs". Thank you Juan and voters for your support.

Answer (score 66):

[image]

I know it's not perfect. A perfect rendition would have more white space on either side of the content :P

Comment: A realistic knitting. :-)

Comment: Hold Mew? What?

Comment: @JL2210-SupportMonica I envy you, not recognizing “HALP ME!!!”

Answer (score 63):

[image]

Comment: DV because scary.

Comment: @WELZ Liar! No you didn't! (Though it is scary.)

Comment: My nightmare before Christmas

Comment: To that I say..... :)

Comment: Help me unsee this!

Comment: My PC _is_ the problem...

Comment: Is this from the Windows 10 Christmas Update?

Comment: That's kinda sad

Comment: @SPA Don't get me started on Windows 10. I'm a Linux user, but have to work on Win 10. I just want to throw some rocks through the windows.

Comment: I want to react with the :joy: emoji.... XD

Comment: @JamesDunn here you go: 

Answer (score 55):

Do you remember [Quack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308564/349538)? He's back!

[image]

Comment: Something different.

Comment: Do you have any grapes?

Comment: That's a good rubber duck answer.

Comment: ... and who else could post a duck pattern? No other than Donald Duck, that's who :P

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MtN1YnoL46Q

Answer (score 54):

[image: Christmas python]

Comment: hello, `''.join(reversed("nohtyp"))` :)

Comment: That's a wonderful knitting!

Comment: A perfect Python :-)

Comment: `print("Merry christmas to all, and to all a good night!")`

Answer (score 48):

[image]

[image]

Comment: TROGDOOOORRRRRRR!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 40):

[image: .]

Answer (score 40):

Some of us MATLAB dorks decided to try and figure out how to automatically format a picture to upload to the knitting tool. After [balpha gave us a hint](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319846/winter-bash-2018-knitting?page=2&tab=votes#comment1047963_319970), we realized that much of what we were doing was pointless. It turns out that you can upload any picture as long as it is a given size: 442 pixels high by 1190 pixels wide. The knitting tool will do all of the resampling and color quantizing for you.

Regardless, I threw together what I had been working on and [put it up on GitHub](https://github.com/kpeaton/knitwit) for anyone interested. `knitwit` can pretty closely recreate the results of the knitting tool, with a couple extra options. Given an image like this:

[image]

It will automatically resize, pad, and recolor the image, adding the knit pattern:

[image]

But you can also turn on a background filling option to get rid of all that white:

[image]

Works on me too:

[image]

And here's [balpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/115866/balpha):

[image]

Hmmm... I wonder what someone could do with a utility that can quickly and easily generate a whole bunch of knitted images...

[image: Never gonna give you up Stack Overflow!]

You've been [knit-rolled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rickrolling)!

If only sweaters could be animated.

Comment: psst... hey, come closer... let me tell you a secret ... all that the editor checks is the dimensions of the uploaded image 

Comment: @balpha: Veeeery interesting...

Comment: @balpha: Buh! All that effort for nothing!!! :)

Comment: How do people even GET these ideas? Wow, everyone here is so knowledgeable and talented...

Comment: @balpha Bah, I wish one could upload an image to a real needle...

Comment: balpha with b in lower case :P

Comment: IIIIIIIII just want to tell you how I'm knitting...

Comment: I'm really more partial to [Taylor Swift](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/320375/282094) over Rick Astley. I thought you were working on a Santa animation.

Answer (score 39):

### Santa is having a bad day :/

[image]

Comment: Has he started already, or is he renewing his license?

Comment: @hat I'd guess that he was testing and calibrating the new upgrades to his slegh. based on the results though, he might just have to go back to last year's model.

Comment: That makes sense; poor Santa's new rocket-assisted scheme did not work as expected. Some reindeer herders told me that the reindeer were threatening to strike. The world population is getting too big, and they are always asking for a hay raise.

Comment: Santa needs AAA.

Answer (score 37):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 37):

My masterpiece is titled "Unicorn at Night."

[image: Unicorn at Night]

Comment: ...The night begins to shine...

Answer (score 37):

[image]

[Wallpaper - blue (1920x1080)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37BVM.png)

[Wallpaper - black (1920x1080)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Qibv.png)

Comment: at-least somebody heard I need rainbows

Comment: Well we already had unicorns so it was only a matter of time...

Comment: Gotta love it! :-)

Answer (score 36):

From RPG.Stackexchange, with love.

[image: D&D_logo]

[image]

Comment: And in case you're interested, over on RPG meta people are making their avatars: https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8617/23970

Comment: Looks great! :)

Comment: Woe that I have but one upvote to give for this knitting.

Comment: Now you only have to knit the rest of the manual too....

Comment: @SPArchaeologist Close enough?

Answer (score 36):

### knit selfie

<sub>(or [knitted selfie](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)?)</sub>

[image]

Updated, not sure if the finished version works as well, but what the heck...

[image]

with the logos of my favourite sites.

**RETRO FAN**

[image]

à la mode van Gogh?

[image]

Comment: Great knit selfie!

Comment: Hi, :-0 Only patience was required to create this or something else?

Answer (score 35):

#### First, a proclamation was made:

From our internal chat:

[image: chat transcript saying that using our knitting tool is a perfectly good excuse for not accomplishing anything]

Because compiling is now *knitting* until the end of the year (reference [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/303/)). Disclaimer: I stink at knitting in any form, pixelated or otherwise.

[image: Horribly drawn take on XKCD 'compiling' cartoon where 'knitting' is the reason the employees are recreating]

Comment: *Knighting* ...

Comment: No, you definitely do not stink at knitting.

Comment: We don't give poor Tim Post enough time to knit! Thankfully he now has a valid excuse.

Comment: Well seeing this post, now I know that I can post my "creation" :-)

Answer (score 32):

[image: FACE SHOG'S WRATH]

Comment: You should have used brown for the shadow man's nose. Looks good :-)

Comment: @Cthulhu Shadows aren't brown... ;-)

Comment: @EKons depends on the light

Comment: @PrincessLuna The type of light for shadowmen is, well, plain white. There are no secondary light sources or anything like that.

Comment: @EKons Theoretically speaking, shadows could be brown. Doesn't necessarily apply here, but it could be applied *somewhere*

Comment: @Cthulhu Are you sure you want to describe Shog like that? He might see your every comment, you know...

Comment: Is it just me who has trouble seeing the face?

Comment: @hat nope, you aren't the only one.

Comment: @SPA I'm glad I'm not the odd one out

Comment: @hat maybe if we saw the original picture Ekons copied...

Comment: @SPArchaeologist Actually, I just pixelated Shog's avatar on SO and tried to knit it afterwards.

Comment: Kinda get it now. I guess I am more used at the floating head one.

Comment: That image is scary enough at small-gravatar size; I'm not sure we can handle it at hat size!

Answer (score 32):

[image: One Does Not Simply ... Knit A Meme]

[image: Ms. Pac-Man]

[image: Mario, Samus Aran, and Simon Belmont]

**[Monoceros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoceros)**, the Unicorn, is an actual (faint) constellation visible this time of year.

[image: Monoceros, the Unicorn]

Comment: Knitting 8-bit video game characters is cheating! -1

Answer (score 29):

[image]

[Tinkeringbell](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/369802/tinkeringbell) avatar, originally posted in the chat. Tinker requested I also post that one here, so...

Comment: I'm not promising anything... but I might try the pattern out later ;)

Comment: psst. Done! https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxQn3.jpg

Answer (score 28):

Last year I [proposed the Top(bar) Hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304640/162102):

[image]

And they implemented it!

[image]

In honor of the occasion, I present my knitted hat.  I'm better with painting than I am with low-res knitting needles, alas.

[image: knitted hat]

Comment: You proposed that hat. But the employee who designed the hat put the icons in wrong order. Review icon should be right to achievement. Probably a bug? ;-D

Comment: @NogShine Might be some sort of symbolism? *Ask, help, earn. This is Stack Exchange.*

Answer (score 28):

[image]

Kind of tried to picture a Targaryen Christmas. The big red thing is supposed to be a three-headed dragon.

Comment: “I am Daenerys of the House Targaryen, the First of Her Name, The Unburnt, Queen of the Andals, the Rhoynar and the First Men, Queen of Meereen, Khaleesi of the Great Grass Sea, Protector of the Realm, Lady Regnant of the Seven Kingdoms, Breaker of Chains and Mother of Dragons”. BEND THE KNEE!  She tried to say the same to me (Tyrion). I avoided that through my talk.

Comment: Should try to knit Y Ddraig Goch when I get some time.

Answer (score 27):

Raise the Union Jack! **God Save the Queen plays**

[image: Union Jack]

Never have I wished for a ruler tool more in my life.

<sup>(This took far too long, curse my darned British patriotism)</sup>

These two were done by my younger sisters :)

[image: Fireworks]

[image: Flag of the USA]

Comment: Bonus points if you can get the saltire to rake correctly :)

Comment: @Davidtoo Not too familiar with flag terminology, what does that mean?

Comment: The saltire is the diagonal cross part. On the official flag, it rakes out to the corners of the flag, rather than at 45 degrees.

Comment: @Davidtoo Ah, so it does. Blast. Maybe another day :)

Answer (score 27):

<sup>*Well this could have turned out much worse than it did.*</sup>

I found it!

[image: knitted chicken]

<sub>[For reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319928/the-lord-of-the-hats-the-return-of-the-chicken)</sub>

Comment: Maybe the chicken event is triggered by a specific knitting pattern? :o

Comment: @PrincessLuna right now, I think our best hope is to manually add the chicken to the original logo picture.

Answer (score 26):

Remember (a better version of) this?

[image: Something like Unikong]

> Tribute to [Sir Jon Skeet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279068/357396) and [Unikong](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unikong) - April 2016 
>  This is available for playing again on [Github](http://stackexchange.github.io/unikong/)

Answer (score 25):

[image]

*For no reason in particular, which do you prefer, cinnamon or butterscotch?*

Answer (score 25):

Best wishes from [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com)

**SQL-Server**

[image]

**PostgreSQL**

[image]

Comment: For sending happiness to *all*, `JOIN LATERAL` might serve better than the non-standard `CROSS APPLY` used by some vendors going their own way. :)

Comment: Hi @ErwinBrandstetter, Evan complaint about it too. It was meant to be `to_everybody`. I'll try to find out a more generic syntax next time.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, Done.

Comment: Ho, ho, ho! :) Or shorter: `CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT to_all FROM dba.se) t` or just `, LATERAL (SELECT to_all FROM dba.se) t` - `JOIN on true` is too noisy for a silent Christmas. (If that much knit-picking is allowed.)

Comment: I see you SQL and raise you a...

Answer (score 25):

Welllll looks like everyone's better than me and I so wish I had my drawing tablet right now but I tried to draw myself:
[image]

Here's a variation of my GitHub profile pic but she looks less done with life and she has a cool hat

[image]

And I wanted to draw StackOverflow as an anime-ish girl idk
[image]

also just asking is this a competition of some sort?

Comment: This is adorable; don't sell yourself short!

Comment: Haha, thanks, but I would have done it on MS Paint if I could then photoshopped it on(I mean my GitHub profile pic was made there...)(and I don't use photoshop because im cheap like that)

Comment: Nope, this isn't a contest; just fun sharing! Awesome picture :D

Comment: What drawing program do you use?

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat Autodesk Sketchbook, mainly on my phone, sometimes on laptop

Comment: Nice pictures. For some reason, the first one has an 80's anime feeling to it. I'm a littler curious, did you by any chance use some old picture as a reference?

Comment: Does it remind you of a certain anime? Because I kinda just thought it up on the spot

Comment: I wasn't alive in the 80s or the 90s, I did however think up a snow fairy design when I was 11 and basically modified that to look like me.

Comment: Saw I got an upvote on this...man, this is some old art of mine. Funny to see how things change over time...

Answer (score 24):

This whole knitting thing felt very 8-bit to me
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Now you just need Mario, Samus Aran, and Simon Belmont.

Comment: To be fair, drawing Link was the first thing I did too.

Answer (score 22):

Just tried to copy as it is :

[image]

Proof that I did :D

[image]

Comment: Great knitting copy!

Answer (score 22):

### Slartibotfast

[image: Worldbuilding robot]

([Reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j98rD.jpg))

The Worldbuilding community mounted a successful campaign to **save the robot** in the new design.  This is my small homage to the bot.

Comment: Fabulous. :) Plus now I don't have to do it.

Answer (score 22):

The Simpsons - S18E6 - [Moe'N'a Lisa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moe%27N%27a_Lisa) - Our favorite k**nit** Homer gets a thorough winter bash.

Approximately 22 minutes into the episode, while making fun of Moe's poetry skills, Homer is skipping across the room and tumbles out the window and down the fire escape.

[Winter Bash 2018](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/) animated knitting version:

[image: Homer takes a tumble down the fire escape - animated knitting]

Original source:

[image: Homer takes a tumble down the fire escape - original]

Comment: I've written a complete tutorial as an answer to a question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/320848/282094

Answer (score 21):

[image: Overlooking a frozen lake at night]

The pink dot is someone taking in the peaceful scenery before running back inside where it's warm.

Comment: Yep, the cozy cabin is the best part.

Comment: Took me a while to notice that pink dot :)

Comment: And what is the yellow dot?

Comment: @Eran Me too :)

Answer (score 20):

ok guys, you can't blame me for trying. My profile picture:

[image]

Comment: haha, gorgeous!

Comment: Yeah, who is this guy

Comment: @alecxe [mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQWYs.png). ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard oh, good, phew, we got him :D

Comment: Nice selfie knit.

Answer (score 20):

The Wolf Constellation, only visible on the Winter Bash with a full moon

[image: Image with a snowman a full moon a tree and a constelation of a wolf, all knitted]

Answer (score 20):

A brainf*** program that prints `Winter bash!`:

[image: bf knitting]

Answer (score 20):

Not to scale...

[image: stargazing knit]

Better than my real life knitting, anyway...

Answer (score 19):

[image]

Answer (score 19):

A happy cephalopod after it just ate a yummy crustacean ;)

[image]

Comment: That would make a great kids sweater! Lovely.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks for the roses, I'm glad you like it ;) If I wouldnt be that terrible in knitting i would make a beanie with hanging tentacles with that design ;)

Answer (score 18):

[image]

Comment: ...but, but, a [Double Rainbow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_Rainbow_(viral_video))! ...what would that mean?

Comment: @Werner I'm not sure there's enough room for another rainbow :)

Comment: Add a face, and this will magically turn to Chica's Magic Rainbow.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist I'm not familiar with that

Comment: @SPArchaeologist I was sure you wrote "China's Magic Rainbow". Not that Chica's makes it more familiar.

Comment: [It's a character from some FNAF game](http://fnaf-world-rpg.wikia.com/wiki/Chica%27s_Magic_Rainbow_(Character)). Never played the actual game, but I heard of it because the part of the game it appears in is basically a big kaizo trap platformer.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist it does look similar to my rainbow! Though mine has more colors

Answer (score 18):

[image]

### What are you talking about? Of course the unicorn wins!!

Comment: Did the chicken lose one of its chicks? One seems to have sneaked into my picture!

Comment: This knitting needs more upvotes :)

Comment: Start the fight. when does it start? Do we need some special glasses? I have Retro. :)

Comment: @Nog: you have to have special super-secret glasses. They are so secret that officially I can neither confirm nor deny that they exist.

Answer (score 18):

Taylor Swift - [Red](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_(Taylor_Swift_song)):

[image: Taylor Swift - Red]

Original, crushed from 14MB to less than 2MB:
[image: Taylor Swift - Red (recompressed from original)]

<sub><sub>Practice makes it better, but not perfect.</sub></sub>

Comment: any animated gifs, good work. How are you doing these? Some kind of tool?

Comment: I like the animations; it's too bad the available color palette is so limited.

Comment: @NogShine - The only tool is my phone and standard online .GIF tools, no scripts or self developed software are used - if I had a computer these entries would be better. To make these I need to guess that the end result will work while trying to decide on a sequence of frames then upload a test frame. Next I create a standard animated .GIF and split it into frames. Each frame is individually uploaded to the knitting machine, downloaded, and reassembled into a .GIF; needless to say that's not lossless, thus the need to predict the result before investing in something that won't work.

Comment: @BrianRogers I mentioned in a comment to the answer that more colors and a bit more vertical resolution would be helpful, some of the CMs are aware of these animations, we'll see what Santa brings us next year. ArtOfCode is working on a tool, you might spot him in The Tavern. PS: I didn't use any tweaks or scripts, upload frame by frame and reassemble the downloaded frames into a standard .GIF using EzGif online editor (on my phone's puny screen).

Comment: **#TeamTayTay**

Answer (score 17):

[image: winterbash_2018_knitting]

Comment: nice knitting!!

Answer (score 17):

**Santa is Coming to Town**

[image: Santa is coming to town]

Answer (score 17):

What can I say? I just love DBA.SE!

[image: I love DBA.SE]

Comment: Love for the most warm se site :)

Answer (score 16):

Here's an attempt to recreate my avatar, which is a cropped version of [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxx7R.jpg), which was custom drawn by [avazula](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/4550/avazula) for me (thanks, ava!):

[image]

This took around an hour on my phone, tapping at the knitting thing...

My avatar, for reference:

[image]

Comment: Wonderful......

Comment: The science logo is missing!

Comment: @NogShine Try to do this logo on your phone :) Good luck.

Comment: avazula  did it better but +1 for attempt

Answer (score 16):

[image: winterbash_2018_knitting]

Comment: +1 for the sun's reflection

Comment: For some weird reasons, this reminds me of the old flash game "The Majesty of Colors"

Comment: Thanks @hat I tried my best with the limited colors. :)

Comment: @SPArchaeologist I never heard of the game before. But now I see that it was great. I may start...

Comment: @MTSan It is very short, but has multiple possible endings. I think it originated on Newsground during some old "artistic games" competition.

Answer (score 16):

## Here's a cat and I named it Meow!

[image]

Comment: That's a cute cat!

Answer (score 16):

[image]

[image]
[image]
<sup>As you can see, Photoshop helped me a little bit here :)</sup>
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Winter Bash 2018 is over! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 15):

An icy rose with a falling star.
[image]

Answer (score 15):

[image]

One logo is not enough... just made another three (Portugues, Spanish and Japanese SO respectively).

Comment: How...just...how do people MAKE these????

Comment: @Eleeza Just work it... ;-)

Answer (score 14):

### Come on, you have to have the red freehand circle!

[image]

Comment: I knew I couldn't have been the first to think of it. +1

Comment: Sorry to steal your thunder @jpmc26! I was beaten to the unicorn, so I thought that I'd better grab the circle. Maybe you could do Jon Skeet? ; )

Answer (score 14):

Tried to make Indian Flag.

Its not perfect but seems like.:)

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Happy Winters :)

[image]

Answer (score 14):

#### My Winter House

---

[image]

Comment: Red chimney and grey smoke?

Comment: @Mari-LouA too many colors! My graphic card has two colors only. ;-)

Answer (score 14):

[image]

Answer (score 14):

## Knitting with hooves is hard

[image]

Comment: The lowest corner should be two stitches lower...good work with hooves, though!

Answer (score 14):

This was really hard without a Wacom tablet (:

[image]

---

[image]

I'm probably gonna add future ones in this post instead of creating a new post for each

Comment: Same here, I want to wait until I get my tablet replaced to do anything else. but then again my GitHub profile pic is made with MS Paint...hmmmm

Comment: I can't get continuous touch outside actual drawing programs. Works fine in Krita, scrolls the website xd And don't get me started on the driver crashing... xD

Comment: Meh, I just use Autodesk Sketchbook because I'm lazy like that XD

Answer (score 14):

Clearly I should not give up my day job...my skating duo is so primitive compared to so many talented "knitters"[image: ![enter image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPnsu.png)

Comment: Naw this is so cute!

Answer (score 14):

[image: twitter logo]

Too soon?

Comment: I, for one, welcome our tweeting overlords.

Comment: Too soon? [Wonder what you would say if you saw Dec 10th joke from my advent calendar on the Time swag contest...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNb41.png)

Answer (score 14):

A keen sweater:

[image: A knitted Commander Keen]

Answer (score 14):

My favorite combo hat: **rubber ducky with waffle**

[image]

"quack"

Comment: in the meantime, the waffle got eaten up by a bunch of sugarholics

Answer (score 13):

[image: Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 13):

[image: Second try]

Answer (score 13):

I have designed the iconic element of one of my favorite sites, [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com).

**THE POPCORN TUB**

[image]

Since there was no color available for different popcorn as per the logo, I had to go with a different color.

Comment: Really nice.....

Answer (score 13):

[image: Ice Crystal]

Answer (score 13):

The Insidious Doktor Mayhem says Merry Christmas!
[image]

Answer (score 13):

Nothing fancy, just a happy snowman with their Christmas tree :)

[image: Snowman with tree]

Answer (score 13):

The **meta-knit**: <sup>(Yo, dawg, I herd you like knits, so I made a knit with a knit so you can knit while you knit)</sup>

[image]

Comment: Meta-knitting needs a bigger canvas though :D

Answer (score 13):

I have a new one, Just few persons can read it ;) can you guess what does mean?

[image]

Hint :

> If you read Arabic it can be more easy ;)

Comment: Aha it says Stack Overflow! btw I’m learning to read the Quran so I know how to read it

Comment: Hi @Eleeza, this is nice to hear this, you are the first who solve it congraduation :)

Comment: Maybe time to tell us by now, what it means ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat says Reinstate Monica it is StackOverflow winter bash 2018 in Arabic 

Answer (score 13):

My knitting seems to have crashed.
[image: BSOD]

Answer (score 13):

## Hats!!! And more Hats!!

[image]

### Thanks for the Winter Bash guys!

---

<sub>Illustration for marketing purposes only. Product colours may vary.</sub> 
<sub><sub><sub>(Limited colours you know)</sub></sub></sub>

Answer (score 13):

**Happy New Year everywhere**, enjoy the fireworks

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Our pink boy is here to save the day and contribute to SO!

[image: Kirby]

Answer (score 12):

[image]

Answer (score 12):

[image: Rubber ducky I am]

Rubber Ducky I am.

Answer (score 12):

Here's my knitted snowflakes
[image]

Answer (score 12):

Rudolph The Red Nosed Reindeer Christmas Cartoon - 1948 Classic - [Source Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o4b9Q7YdDdM)

The scene at 3:37 where [Santa calls his reindeer](https://youtu.be/o4b9Q7YdDdM?t=3m36s) (video link) to the sleigh:
[image: Santa calls his reindeer - knitting machine output]

Original input to the knitting machine, heavily recompressed to meet 2MB limit:
[image: Santa calls his reindeer - knitting machine input]

Answer (score 11):

Good cup of coffee with Java :

[image: Hi Java]

Comment: You keep surprising me ;-) (now that I spent a bit more of time over here)

Answer (score 10):

[image: abeta - before]
<sup><sup>Before</sup></sup>

[image: balpha - after]
<sup><sup>After</sup></sup>

Now about that chicken ...

Comment: That guy looks familiar.

Comment: Wha----photorealism?!

Comment: Did you "hand knit" it or use some photoshop/Gimp programme to get that fantastic shading so spot on? If the former, bravo! If the latter... then could you explain how it was done? I was thinking what it reminded me of and now it's hit me, the Obama campaign poster, only the colours used were mostly red and blue, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - balpha [evolved naturally](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dyed-in-the-wool).

Answer (score 10):

Standing proud for the functional folks out here.

[image: Caution...made with secret alien technology]

Answer (score 10):

Check My night mode effect

[image]

Answer (score 10):

For balpha:

[image: our unicorn]

Those of you who do not get the reference see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uipTZ2re4Uk).

Comment: I love it! ❤

Comment: Ahh, finally something for the one who is behind this knitting fun we all are having. Looks good. Thanks for the video too.

Answer (score 10):

[image: Winter Bash]

or what about this classic Snake game.
[image: Winter Bash]

Comment: Snake is really nice! :)

Answer (score 10):

[image]

Answer (score 10):

My humble offering[image]

Answer (score 9):

[image: T-Bone Steak]
<sup><sup>First Food Entry</sup></sup>

Comment: This is really weird. I like it.

Answer (score 9):

## MoAr FrEeHaNd

[image]

Comment: This looked like a guy laying a puddle of milk to me at first :P ...

Comment: @Laurel I see that now, can't unsee it.

Comment: @Laurel Wait, it's not? What is it supposed to look like?

Comment: @AndyD273 it's a freehand circle with an arrow pointing towards it.

Comment: @Laurel I think you mean a guy laying **in** a puddle of milk (actually, at that rate, it should be lying). Crucial word otherwise he is laying the puddle like a chicken would lay an egg...

Comment: It's a crime scene with the colors inverted

Comment: @WELZ meta is a funny place, all you have to do  is include a meme and it does the work for you

Comment: @pushkin Right :)

Comment: It's like a dead XKCD guy ;-)

Answer (score 9):

**Behold, the Goofholder**

[image]

Answer (score 9):

**The sun is wearing the «Retro Fan» secret hat with 7 colors rainbow**

[image]

> **[Rainbow on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow)**

Answer (score 9):

Here are some firey logs.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I love trees, I love looking at them and I love drawing them. So, can you guess what I decided to knit?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Here's a helpful thing telling you what not to do.

[image: don't panic]

With its eye-catching background, and encouraging message, having this on your towel will make you a true hoopy frood. Limited offer only.

(getting those diagonal lines took *forever*, though)

Answer (score 9):

I spotted some strange clouds while skywatching...

[image: clouds with SO, SE, and SU logos]

Answer (score 9):

stack-overflow, do you love it?

[image]

Do you have an account on it? how much rep you ahve?

Comment: please edit the second line without caps locks

Comment: btw. use a transparent *.gif or *.png image 
the size should be 1190 x 442 pixel
P.S.: if the image is transparent you can set first the knitting canvas to any other color

Answer (score 8):

Well, since other people have contributed their country's flag, I figured I'd try my hand at it as well.

It's... not exactly centered, but I blame that on the odd shape of the canvas.

[image: Israeli flag]

Comment: The shape of the canvas isn't odd. It is [irregular hexacontakaihexagon.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/320049/357396) which has some fat issues. :)

Answer (score 8):

Obligatory **[Aquaman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquaman_(film))** post:

[image: Aquaman_knit]

Comment: wow nice............

Comment: It would be definitely better with Mahadev (Shiva)! ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Lots of love and Merry Christmas from the Netherlands to all of you!

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Top view of road
[image: road view]

Answer (score 7):

To celebrate the [Stack Overflow is 10](https://stackoverflow.com/anniversary).

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Image source: [my own old domino tower photo](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5698/14253).

Answer (score 6):

In honour of the greatest colour to ever exist!

[image]

Answer (score 6):

My country's<sup>1</sup> flag was missing here, and turns out the star is the hardest part!

[image]

<sup>1</sup> Guess the country without checking my profile :)

Comment: Foiled, alas, the city name immediately came to my head which was obviously incorrect because it's not the name of your country. But I recognized it!

Comment: @TimPost Glad you recognized it!

Answer (score 6):

```
> I   H O P E    I T   L I K E S   Y O U
>
```

[image: I hope it L I K E S Y O U]

---

I made this upgraded version *(without image of reference)* - just remebering about the details I saw in the past...

> I haven't play the game, though.

[image: I M P R O V I N G...]

Answer (score 6):

Here is mine. I guess it takes a while to load these things?

[image: My knit]

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The WB is over, the hats are gone, and the snowflake is again missing from the top bar.
The only thing left to say is:
[image: That's all Folks!]

*tried* to copy the old [looney toons ending](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oUCv.jpg)

Comment: Lovely. Have 10 rep for your effort.

Answer (score 5):

It's getting cold out here!
[image]

Comment: Wear a [Christmas sweater](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/320127/357396). There is a choice of color too.

Answer (score 5):

Winter Bash is my favorite, because I hate winter.

[image]

Comment: +1 for not making sense

Comment: @Davidthethird You might consider retracting your upvote, because it [does make sense](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Abash&rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS819US819&oq=define%3Abash&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.1535j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) :)

Comment: Ohh, I get it now.

Answer (score 5):

**The leaning tower of waffles**

inspired by [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_Tower_of_Pisa) world famous monument

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps a bit of a Me2 but getting the proportions right required a bit of playing around with the GMIP...

[image: My avatar in glorious knitwear]

Answer (score 4):

Everyone's favorite communication method at work and Stack Exchange's newest *Teams* integration:

[image: Slack Knit]

Answer (score 4):

this is for my friend [@U9-Forward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8708364/u9-forward):

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Vickel, i love it, :-)

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Some Winter Bash regular thing:

[image]

Or:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

My knitting is an homage to my ancestors (Italians, Scots and Swedes).
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Winter Bash, why not, the snowflake looks cool!:[image]

Answer (score 2):

I made a happy face :)

[image]

It's my first time knitting

Answer (score 1):

In tribute of [6 to 8 Weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/182734) meme:

[image]

Comment: In tribute of [pluralisation bugs!](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105) :D

Comment: Evergreen meme. Works for any contest.

Comment: I see this earned you a hat! See, 6-8 does everything.

Comment: @NogShine but it will still take 6-8 week for cheesy swag :D

Answer (score 1):

Do you know him?
[image]
It's my first knitting.

Answer (score 0):

My little contribution with some secret transcription ^^

[image]

Some spoilers to resolve the puzzle (xD):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

my attempt at a symmetrical shape:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Answer (score -3):

[image]

[image: 2.0]

Answer (score -5):

This is an artistic and very well thought out work of art.

[image]

Comment: Everyone is a crittic xD - 
it reminds me to the old savecreen in Windows *(Vista, or XP?, I think)*?

Comment: Knit, knot, same difference. A knitted knot. So meta!