# What is the shape of the Knitting canvas?

Tags: support, design, winter-bash, fun, winter-bash-2018

The knitting canvas of [Winter Bash 2018](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/) has a weird shape:

> [image: knitting canvas]

What is this shape supposed to represent, if anything?

Comment: I've always assumed it was a cloud...

Comment: @Glorfindel cloud of love? :-)

Comment: It's the exact shape that my belly makes when I'm brushing my teeth in the morning.

Comment: @Snow that's new to me. Belly making shape when brushing teeth?! lol

Comment: Maybe the chicken is to blame?!

Comment: It's the [flying spaghetti monster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Spaghetti_Monster) ;)

Comment: Almost like an Alvar Aalto vase

Comment: 1)Ahhh the chicken lololol 2)I don't got the flying spaghetti thing. 3)Bellies move when brushing teeth? 4)I think it's a showy island or an "opened up part of the space-time continuum for your convenience to let your creativity out as you wish"

Comment: @ShadowWizard if you accept my answer I'll get a wizard hat... Feel free to move the check after an hour.

Answer (score 17):

It's the shape of a happy cephalopod after it just ate a yummy crustacean ;)

[image]

Comment: This specific cephalopod actually has a [twin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319846/winter-bash-2018-knitting/320142#320142) ;)

Comment: A desire to own a pair of socks with this design on them just struck me with a rather curious sense of urgency.

Comment: @TimPost I'd gladly help if I'd had any 5 Cents to my knitting skills, but I might know somebody that can perform those ninja like moves and gets the job done (I'll send them to your HQ).  If I would try I'd probably end up with one knitting needle in my left eye lobotomizing myself ;)

Comment: [Here's a work-in-progress](https://i.imgur.com/ka7krLS.png) but the wording on the scientific classification just feels incorrect to me.

Comment: @TimPost That looks amazing! Maybe `Amores Cephalopodores`? ;)

Answer (score 15):

### The shape is an *irregular hexacontakaihexagon*.

See [this chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon#Constructing_higher_names) for how to find names for shapes like this.

Answer (score 12):

My money is on a 4-sleeved pair programming sweater, with the bottom two arm holes being for your code companion to also reach the keyboard.

Comment: 

Comment: So you subscribe to the theory that, like sex, coding is more fun when done with somebody else?

Comment: @slysven, I almost do, with the stipulation that the sweater-wearers have complete control of the number of under layers present, depending on their relationship and the feature at hand.

Comment: Well, yes, the *physically* relationship does have some bearing on it - compare the fore-and-aft arrangement that can work for both the above activities at any level of ability whereas the lateral arrangement where the participants are side-by-side like on a piano-stool playing a duet; now that does require more skilled practitioners!

Answer (score 7):

It's OBVIOUSLY the shape of a knitted t-shirt!

- The very top is very thin, because it's the neckline.
- The middle is also thinner, because the waistline is usually shorter than the chest line. Note that the sleeves' ends can be simply cut off.
- The belly is the fattest, so as to accommodate for people who aren't exactly flat-bellied (they deserve some love too). Also, a t-shirt shouldn't be too tight, it's supposed to be a comfortable garment.
- Finally, the bottom is a bit thinner than the belly, since the belly ends a little before the t-shirt's bottom. That is because otherwise cold can easily get inside the t-shirt, rendering it moot.

Those characteristics of the t-shirt may look exaggerated, since the canvas is a bit stretched horizontally and squeezed vertically.

Another clue:

> @TimPost [...] Guess no chance for actual swag for top answers? :) – [Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859/shadow-wizard) [Dec 12 '18 at 14:42](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319846/winter-bash-2018-knitting?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment1047909_319846)

That comment got this reply:

> @ShadowWizard **There ... might be something in the works.** I can not confirm nor deny any things for any things. But there might be things, or other things. But the thing is, the things are the way they are because of other things, so we'll just have to thing positively and see. – [Tim Post♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/50049/tim-post) [Dec 12 '18 at 14:48](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319846/winter-bash-2018-knitting?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment1047910_319846)

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Tim tried to cover up for his first sentence, as you can see if you read carefully.

As we all know, t-shirts are very frequent swag! Maybe the shape of the canvas is a hint that swag does indeed exist?

Comment: I like that interpretation, but the size of the knitting stitches rules out actually rolling the thing into a shirt as-is.

Comment: @NH. I might not be able to explain the misrepresentation that has happened on the canvas... as I said, the canvas has been squeezed in one dimension and stretched in the other, but the stitches have then been resized to normal and... yeah, it's confusing, but there is an explanation. ;-P

Comment: This is so crazy that it might be true... ;)