# How do I return to the original image?

Tags: discussion, support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2018

Before clicking on "Done", I had this image before starting to knit. Now I can't see it, because I have an old image replaced. Can I return to this original image?
<sup>Image used from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319890/403480).</sup>
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Click on Save/Load:

[image]

and then on Reset:

[image]

to retrieve the original image.