# Winter Bash 2019 - is it happening this year?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2019

On a lighter note for meta, I was wondering if there was any heads up on a start date. From past years it looks like we're about a month out.

I'm a huge fan of any hat targets that focus on answering unanswered questions (I mean, isn't that the point), especially old questions (> 6 months, for example).  Or for offering bounties - it's the season of giving!

(stops short of suggesting a Monica hat)

[Some others have suggested hats for 2019](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/321554/149926)

Comment: The bounty is mine, mine, all mine, I tell you  *Muahahaha* (hysterical laughing ensues)

Comment: @Mari-LouA no it's not! Well, almost! ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [❄️ Winter Bash 2019 Hat list ❄️](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339891/%ef%b8%8f-winter-bash-2019-hat-list-%ef%b8%8f)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes. It is.

[Tick Tock](https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: That was ... unexpected.

Comment: I guess it's... time

Comment: Best of luck, guys. The other answers still stand -- you know what I think about this.

Comment: So we will get exactly what we had in 2018, with the knitting tool and same hats? 

Comment: Based on the counter, it would start in 5 days - 12/9. That's very early. If it lasts the usual 3 weeks it won't cover the new year. I hope it's not going to be an exact rerun of last year (as the exact same countdown might suggest).

Comment: It is the same theme as 2018 (and yes, you can knit once more). Sorry, not enough bandwidth here to make a brand new theme this time around. And the knitting is pretty cool. (Mostly) different hats and missions. And even though it is starting on the 9th, it will run through the end of Jan 1 (as usual)

Comment: @YaakovEllis Thanks for your reply. I'm looking forward to it!

Comment: Yeah this is _definitely_ what SO should spend its resources on. Lets all sit down and _knit_ while the house is _still_ on fire.

Comment: @Lundin consider this as letting the innocent people who are still in the house have some fun.

Comment: @Sha, shouldn't we be thinking about evacuating them instead? Knitting is not exactly fireproof.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi find a safe place with the same life style and we can begin. :-)

Comment: YaakovEllis there were many requests to slightly increase the resolution and significantly improve the palette of the Knitting Machine - I hope it wasn't too much trouble to change a few numbers and that this year's knitting can be even better.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Rob. No promises, but we'll see...

Comment: [Bugs approves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/320098/282094) that message. 

Comment: I find it interesting that my comment expressing my lack of excitement got deleted.

Comment: @Rob I'll see what I can do. Changing the resolution of the "loom" actually breaks a number of dependencies that rely on it being the way that it is right now, and there probably isn't enough time to fix that. Expanding the palette will hopefully be more achievable. Not making any promises. We'll see.

Comment: @Rob the problem is that the header image (which you can see [a screenshot of here](https://contests.stackoverflow.com/promos/19/winter-bash-2018)) is not a static image. It is actually generated on the fly on the same loom that you can draw on if you "start knitting". So if we were to change the resolution, it would end up requiring us to recode that entire header image. So a simple change, with big side effect.

Comment: YaakovEllis - I pulled the [specs from last year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/320848/282094). I understand that the redesigning must be as easy as possible. Here is a [*lake reflection* design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bP30.jpg) (the *Button* in the center only needs to appear once (not reflected), or could be on the bottom). That is simply **2x** last year's vertical resolution. A subsequent reload/replacement of your *new* header image would be with the user's last save. Other [promo pages](https://contests.stackoverflow.com/promos/4/mass-effect-3-missions) were different sizes. IDK.

Comment: @Rob try again now please. Also, please note the new brush that I made for you. Sorry, but there just wasn't enough time to change anything about the header.

Comment: Yaakov, there was more missing than met the eye. I use FF Android in Desktop View (as do quite a few people). After the fix it looks *sufficiently* fine in [landscape mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKAwA.jpg) (I didn't realize that a couple of colors were completely missing), though it *could* be centered on the page better. **But** in [portrait mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpUy4.jpg) the leftmost (newly revealed) swatch is half  a circle too far to the left, though the centering is better (but not exact). --- I am OK, no priority to fix for me. Thanks for making it better. [Continued].

Comment: Minor? Point: In addition, the **3rd Brush** is one pixel too big (in **my** opinion) and makes a (relatively) *big* jump in size between the second and third brush + look at it this way, if there were a 4th brush how wide would it be?, 8 pixels (ouch).

Answer (score 113):

## If it does, I'm not excited for it.

To me, that would paint the picture like everything is fine, the community is happy and we can all enjoy the winter festivities. It's like pretending that nobody got hurt, as if no harm was done, and as if the biggest problem Stack Exchange, Inc. and the community has right now is picking which hats to add.

**That would be a bold-faced lie.**

Things are not okay, and pretending like they are wouldn't make it better. I sincerely hope that there will not be a Winterbash 2019.

Comment: These are my sentiments as well. There is only one way I'd be interested in participating in SE's traditional winter festivities: if Monica's moderator status was reinstated first, and she had donated her GoFundMe legal fees to charity. In that case, I'd be all in. Barring that, though – Winter Hats? Hand me a barf bag, please.

Comment: @J.R.means'JustReinstate' As far as I am aware, it's not just about the reinstatement, but more about the continuous slander and personal attacks from SE, Inc.

Comment: I hate to break it to you, but in a lot of SE 'corners' everything **is** fine, the sub-community is happy and nobody has even noticed recent events.  In fact, there isn't and never has been a single 'community' but always many, whose only connections points are the use of the same Q&A platform.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl Yes, I am completely aware that this entire "event", so to speak, is mostly limited to meta. The reason simply being that meta is the place to discuss this. Other sites will likely not debate this topic there (as it would be off-topic anyways), so users who exclusively stick to a main site will not have come in contact with it. However, many sites suffered as a direct result of these actions (e.g. the Workplace) due to moderator resignation.

Comment: "The reason simply being that meta is the place to discuss this" And also that a lot of users (even regular users) simply do not care about so-called community issues -- you have to be passionate about them to bother coming to Meta. And also have a high degree of tolerance for continued drama.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl Undoubtedly true. Most users don't care that something is wrong until it directly affects them. However, I would consider the fact that many highly-active users are unhappy with the platform to be a threat to this status quo. If highly active experts leave, then answer quality will drastically be reduced.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl While "most users" may not know much about this, a much larger portion of big contributors and long-time users _do_ know about it. You can't compare someone with 200 rep who joined a year ago with someone with 90k rep who has been here since the beginning.

Comment: @TheforestofReinstateMonica And that's another thing that's wrong with a single 'community' concept -- I can't speak about SO which is a beast sui generis, but on the smaller sites, we care as much about the opinions and feelings of somebody with 200 rep who joined a year ago as we do about the people who have been on the site from the beginning and have (for that site) high rep.  More so -- the newcomers are why we exist in the first place.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl The idea that long-term users are replacable as long as you keep pushing enough fresh meat into the grinder is what put us into this mess in the first place.

Comment: @MechMK1 Did I say long term users were replaceable? I didn't. I said new users were as important a part of the so-called community as the long term users -- if the new users don't stick around the old guard are just shouting in an echo chamber, and if the old guard doesn't stick around the new users might have to answer each other's questions.

Comment: Hehe just got [my first hat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1I7Ih.png)  - this company is obsessed 

Answer (score 70):

## I wouldn't hold my breath.

Back in January, months before the current sequence of train wrecks started landing on us, [there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321554/suggestions-for-winter-bash-2019#comment1052792_321554) [were](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/321577/164403) [signs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/321862/164403) that hats had overstayed their welcome, so to speak. We basically have been rehashing the same thing every year for a while now, the concept is growing old, and ideas for new, interesting hats have grown scarce.

In addition, traditionally the whole hats challenge has implied *increasing participation* on the sites, particularly in *moderation activities*. I think I'm not spoiling anyone when I say that many users are currently in quite the opposite mood here.

And last, but not least, Stack Exchange going festive again as if nothing was happening would not strike me as the right move to make. At best, it could appear as them handwaving the current situation and trying to get back to business as usual. At worst, it could appear as them taking us for dumb goldfish that will happily line up to contribute to the sites again as soon as they add a little gamification.

**I think that ship has sailed. Really.**

Comment: **it could appear as them handwaving the current situation and trying to get back to business as usual** They've **been** doing that already. All I've seen in the last couple of weeks is a bunch of blog entries trying to make it look like business as usual. Some good, some kind of ridiculous IMHO. And some I haven't bothered to read past the first paragraph. But **nothing** about the problems of the last several weeks.

Comment: @manassehkatz, I'm afraid the blog's intended audience is not us. It appears to target the new, massive, enthusiast community Stack Exchange believes will replace us. Of course, they would not speak on that venue about the crisis with the *existing* community.

Comment: I'm not privy to what's going on with Winter Bash (literally heard nothing about it myself, but maybe I missed something), but a major factor to keep in mind is our [chief architect of fun things](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/115866/balpha?tab=profile) no longer works for us.

Comment: @animuson, dang, I wasn't aware of that. Well, that settles things, then.

Comment: Fun has a bus factor of 1? :/

Comment: @Journeyman, probably not, but IIRC in the past "fun" events have required some "push" from the inside of the dev team, as well as considerable dedication of one or more of them for a few days / weeks. balpha being out (and others being quite busy) does not bode well for that to happen right now.

Comment: @animuson tbf balpha has not personally done winterbash for years (e.g. Oded and I did one)

Comment: @Sklivvz That was the year when I was a PM -- after going back to dev, I did work on WB.

Comment: @animuson I did however spend a lot of time during my last weeks at the company documenting the implementation on SO Internal 

Comment: @balpha did a crazy amount of documentation. I would be *so* lost right now without it. And he also helped me out in a pinch last week as well. Much thanks!

Comment: For 10K users only....https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337641/223820