# Is this a recycled Winter Bash?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2019

There was a lot of stuff happening on SE which I can't say was positive. Keeping it aside I was looking out for Winter Bash which might bring some positivity and to my surprise, it's here ([countdown](https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/)).

But, is it a recycled 2018 Winter Bash? In previous years, the Winter Bash page used to have a unique design but now it's just the knitting theme of 2018. Can we have more news about it?

Comment: That kind of ruins the excitement of the countdown, doesn't it?

Comment: Take out your *old* sweaters and start knitting.

Comment: Re *"was a lot of stuff happening"*: I would say ongoing.

Answer (score 23):

**The design (and knitting) is the same, but the hats will be largely different.**

According to [Yaakov Ellis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337910/winter-bash-2019-is-it-happening-this-year?rq=1#comment1134022_339591):

> It is the same theme as 2018 (and yes, you can knit once more). Sorry, not enough bandwidth here to make a brand new theme this time around. And the knitting is pretty cool. (Mostly) different hats and missions. And even though it is starting on the 9th, it will run through the end of Jan 1 (as usual) – Yaakov Ellis♦

Answer (score 17):

It seems the answer is yes on the design but they'll be different hats and missions. In the [following comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337910/winter-bash-2019-is-it-happening-this-year#comment1134022_339591) Stack Overflow developer [Yaakov Ellis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/51/yaakov-ellis) said:

> It is the same theme as 2018 (and yes, you can knit once more). Sorry, not enough bandwidth here to make a brand new theme this time around. And the knitting is pretty cool. (Mostly) different hats and missions. And even though it is starting on the 9th, it will run through the end of Jan 1 (as usual)