# How many people have won hats during different years?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

I am trying to find the number of people participating in WB each year.
"Participate in WB" means that acquiring at least one hat of that year's WB.
Is there any way I can achieve that?

Comment: The best you can do is go over the [Farewell wb blog posts](https://stackoverflow.blog/tag/winter-bash/)

Comment: You can participate without even knowing, hats are awarded just for visiting the tour page, upvoting or editing a post.

Answer (score 6):

**The number of participants in Winter Bash each year has not been part of the statistics released after every WB. The closest data to what you're looking for is the "distinct users" count.**

The "distinct users" number sums the number of users earning each hat available and counts a user only once, even if they earned the hat on multiple sites.

| Winter Bash | Hats awarded | Distinct users |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2012 | 108,924 | 46,710 |
| 2013 | 214,172 | 76,586 |
| 2014 | 244,865 | 84,439 |
| 2015 | 322,747 | 72,182 |
| 2016 | 797,074 | 215,960 |
| 2017 | 546,504 | 173,054 |
| 2018 | 604,043 | 335,281 |
| 2019 | 265,946 | 163,865 |

Sources:

- [2012](https://stackoverflow.blog/2013/01/08/boxing-day), [2013](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/01/03/winter-bash-2013-wrap-up), [2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245680/collect-hat-stats-please), [2015](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272735/winter-bash-2015-post-mortem), [2016](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289668/can-we-have-a-2016-winter-bash-wrap-up-with-stats), [2017](https://web.archive.org/web/20180110151511/https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/stats), [2018](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/01/04/adios-to-winter-bash-2018) and [2019](https://web.archive.org/web/20200106164615/winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/stats).
- From Winter Bash 2017 onwards, refer to [Do we have comparative statistics for Winter Bash 2019?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341456/do-we-have-comparative-statistics-for-winter-bash-2019).

Comment: I looked at those blog pages but I didn't see any number related to the total number of users. A user can be a member on multiple sites and earn more than one hat. E.g. I earn a secret hat on one site, but a different one on another site. Does the system still count me as one distinct user or as two distinct users?

Comment: @Mari-LouA It counts you as one user no matter how many sites you get the same hat on. From the 2019 source I linked: "The "distinct users" number counts a user only once, even if they earned the hat on multiple sites."

Comment: But I can earn different hats on different sites. E.g. I earn "Amazing Grace" on Meta but earn "Where in the World?" on ELL. two different hats on two different sites. I do not mean to say earning the same hat on 20 different sites.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I've updated my answer to clarify that the stats the OP is looking for is not released as far as I'm aware. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Can you provide the data sources for 2013 and 2012 so that I can cite them?

Comment: @Jason Updated my answer with the sources for 2012 & 2013.

Comment: @Jason I figured that the numbers I used for Winter Bash 2017 onwards were incorrect so I have updated them. Sources for the new numbers are take from [Do we have comparative statistics for Winter Bash 2019?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341456/do-we-have-comparative-statistics-for-winter-bash-2019).