# No Winter Bash Knitting this year (2020)?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

Is there no Winter Bash knitting this year, like in [2019](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339896/winter-bash-2019-knitting)? How about other seasons?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no knitting this year. Knitting was only supposed to be available in Winter Bash 2018; it was repeated as a special circumstance in Winter Bash 2019.

Winter Bash usually takes on a different theme<sup>1</sup> every year, except for [last year's](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/12/09/tis-the-season-for-hats-join-us-for-winter-bash-2019/) (2019) which was a ["recycled" Winter Bash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339601/is-this-a-recycled-winter-bash).

> It is the same theme as 2018 (and yes, you can knit once more). Sorry, not enough bandwidth here to make a brand new theme this time around. And the knitting is pretty cool. (Mostly) different hats and missions. And even though it is starting on the 9th, it will run through the end of Jan 1 (as usual)
>  from [Yaakov Ellis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337910/winter-bash-2019-is-it-happening-this-year#comment1134022_339591)

That also explains why knitting was available for two consecutive Winter Bashes (due to the recycled Winter Bash theme).

<sup>1</sup>The theme I'm referring to is the site design which sometimes comes with a game / activity as part of the theme, e.g. knitting in 2018/19 and the Hat Dash game in 2020.

Comment: So, for completeness, what's the theme this year?

Comment: Worth adding that the reason for the limited bandwidth at the time was that the employee responsible for most of the "fun" in Winter Bash (balpha) left the company in March 2019. That's also why you don't see things like chicken quests or other "strange" occurrences in 2019 and onward.

Comment: I endorse this answer. Though I contest the claim that there are no "fun" elements added to this years event.

Comment: @YaakovEllis Oh the game was fun! "site design which sometimes comes with a game / activity, e.g. ... the Hat Dash game in 2020"

Comment: I've been waiting the whole year to knit stupid and ugly things :( I really hate 2020

Comment: @YaakovEllis hi, any fun elements this year? Still didn't find any. :)