# Do we know the exact number of participants in each year's Winter Bash?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

I wonder: is there a way to know the exact number of participants* in each year's Winter Bash?
I am interested in knowing the exact number of participants from the Stack Overflow community in the past three or four years.

*By participant I mean any user who has earned at least one hat during the event

Comment: You're going to need to define "participant". What action, if any, by a user qualifies them as a "participant". A user could easily earn one or more hats without actually participating, but by just using the site as they normally do, perhaps with just ignoring all the Winter Bash stuff and/or blocking it with an ad blocker, etc. Is the user considered a participant if they clicked on the "no hats" (or whatever it was called that year) button, but still performed actions which would have gotten them one or more hats?

Comment: @Makyen Thanks. I added my intended definition to the post

Comment: I'd suggest that "participation" can be gauged by how many people visit the Winter Bash web page - this should be a pretty accurate, simple task.  Simply going by hats isn't accurate as people get those as part of their day-to-day use of the network (which is pretty much just asking "How many people were active on Stack Exchange between two dates?")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, we don't know the exact number. See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/359232/295232) for how many people actually *wore* a hat (in the last three years); neither the [stats page](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/stats) nor the [closing blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/01/05/ciao-winter-bash-2020/) state the actual number of participants according to your definition. The stats page does say 1,850,311 distinct users (of the Stack *Exchange* network, not just Stack Overflow) have earned the Social Distancing (Main) hat, so it's pretty safe to say the actual number you're looking for is very close to that number, because it's very unlikely to earn a hat without visiting the site. It can be done:

- Mariachi and Happy New Year (related to starred chat messages, you don't need to visit the main site)
- Eliza Doolots (you can gain reputation from old posts without visiting)
- Defender of the Unicorn (also related to non-Q&A sites)
- Wa-boushi (you can gain a Guru badge for an old answer)
- perhaps Carmen (if the suggestion was before Winter Bash, but the approval during)

For other years: [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20200106164615/https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/stats) is the stats page for 2019; there is a screenshot of stats in the closing blog. Closing blog posts are [here (2019)](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/01/15/winter-persists-but-winter-bash-2019-has-drawn-to-a-close/) and [here (2018)](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/01/04/adios-to-winter-bash-2018/).

Your best bet would be that a friendly Community Manager comes along and reads and answers this (if it's even possible to do that for older Winterbashes).