# Let's not have hats on Meta Stack Exchange for 2019

Tags: discussion, feature-request, meta, community, winter-bash-2019

The idea of Winter Bash 2019 has...not been popular among Meta regulars. It [does](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339591/336163) look like it is going forward in general.

Could we make an exception and remove Meta Stack Exchange from the sites participating in Winter Bash this month? This would allow the general festivities to continue among people not invested in the recent fall drama but allow us to maintain a more somber attitude here. It used to be that sites had to have discussions on their per-site Metas in order to determine if they would participate - this post could be considered a similar thread.

Comment: I think the votes speak for themselves, but really -- just because you and I do not think it is a good idea does not mean we have the right to deprive others of it. The band is still playing. As others have said, let them enjoy it while it lasts.

Comment: Isn’t there a “I hate hats” button for this purpose?

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones yes, but this would be a "This site hates hats" nuclear option.

Comment: @Rebecca, absolutely. And you don't even have to click it, you just have to ignore the snowflake icon or fail to whitelist this year's site in your adblocker. I don't have a problem with Winter Bash occurring this year, I just don't think it's a good idea, 's all.

Comment: And we don't have it. (At least when I open the 'hat page', I am greeted with the same old theme (as already hinted at, indeed) but also with the 'text' clearly saying "2018". Feels howling hollow…

Comment: @jitendrasingh Is it really necessary to drag this question back to daylight with such an unnecessary edit?

Answer (score 22):

1. Use the "I hate hats" button so that you don't see any hats and don't don any yourself.
2. Downvote any posts about Winterbash, since they'll be "not useful" to you.
3. Profit!
4. (If you feel it's appropriate) Upvote any posts that mention "Reinstate Monica" hats.

Comment: So what If I make a post about the winter bash *and* about "the one who must not be mentioned"? UV or DV?

Comment: @David  If it was mostly about Monica, I'd probably upvote because I think reminders of how SE screwed up are worthwhile.  YMMV

Comment: Ant hat that mentions "reinstate Monica" will probably be deleted by any one of the three mods. I know because  my [peaceful tribute](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/338416/revisions) "Reinstate Monica" was deleted. Note the reason for censoring the image is: `This answer was marked as spam or rude or abusive `

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't see how your knitting post could be considered rude or abusive, I guess it's only a matter of time before usernames aren't allowed to include "Reinstate Monica."

Comment: All those posts were censored away, as were most comments pointing this out.