# ❄️ Winter Bash 2019 Hat list ❄️

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2019, secret-hats

The Winter Bash is back and the hats are listed below.

As always, there are only two answers: one for the secret hats, and one for the regular hats. The secret hat list will be updated as we learn them.

*Only edit the secret hat answer with **definitive and correct triggers**. This is not the place to post guesses.*

If you'd like to discuss Winter Bash, hats or just have a question about the WB please come over to the [Winter Bash c*hat* room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101913/tarnish-web-2019).

Please keep the comments here clean. As always comments are not meant for discussion, conversation, "I just got hat X", etc use the [c*hat* room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101913/tarnish-web-2019) for that (the remaining meta mods will periodically clean the comments).
I know you are excited you just got a secret hat, but please instead of posting a comment come over to the [c*hat* room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101913/tarnish-web-2019) and tell us all there.

Provided that "It's important to know your history... in more ways than one"  again this year, here are the hats from prior years:

[Winter Bash 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319838/278094)
[Winter Bash 2017](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304340/278094)
[Winter Bash 2016](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288271/278094)
[Winter Bash 2015](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270789/278094)
[Winter Bash 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245170/278094)

Answer (score 62):

## Secret hats for Winter Bash 2019

*Click on each of the hats for a larger image.*

---

#### The Merlin

[image: The Merlin]

> Earn an [Enlightened](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/19/enlightened) badge. *(Hat and trigger from 2018)*

---

#### Warm Welcome

[image: Warm Welcome]

Note: Design of hat was modified during WB, see [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340512/this-star-on-the-warm-welcome-hat-looks-like-a-communist-symbol) for more information.

> Upvote any user's first post. *(Hat and trigger from 2014)*

---

#### Universe Brain

[image: Universe Brain]

> Earn the [Great Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/25/great-answer) badge. [Answer score of 100 or more] *(Hat and trigger from 2017)*

---

#### This Is Fine

[image: This Is Fine]

> Answer a bountied question but don't receive the bounty, and have a [positive score when](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340757/282094) the calculation script is run. Answer must be posted during the bounty period but not necessarily during Winter Bash. If you answer your own question, have a positive score, and offer the bounty you win this hat when you award the bounty. *(Hat and trigger from 2016)*

---

#### 007

[image: 007]

For hats awarded *before* 2019-12-19 12:04 UTC:

> Post an answer scoring at least +7 with 0 comments on the question and 0 comments on the answer. *(Hat and trigger from 2015)*

For hats awarded *after* 2019-12-19 12:04 UTC:

> Post an answer scoring at least +7 to a question that also scores at least +7

The trigger for the hat was [changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340565/377214) at the stated time due to a design flaw in the prior trigger (it somehow ended up being the same as that of the hat below). Users who had already earned this hat get to keep it, though they can have it removed upon request if they wish to guess the new trigger.

---

#### Blue in the Face

[image: Blue in the Face]

For hats awarded *before* 2019-12-19 12:04 UTC:

> Post an answer scoring at least +7 with 0 comments on the question and 0 comments on the answer. *(Hat and trigger from 2015)*

For hats awarded *after* 2019-12-19 12:04 UTC:

> answer +7 during WB, where the question has at least 7 comments made in WB that were not made by the answer poster. (Confirmed by Yaakov Ellis [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53092257#53092257) after Winter Bash)

The trigger for the hat was [changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340565/377214) at the stated time due to a design flaw in the prior trigger (it somehow ended up being the same as that of the hat above). Users who had already earned this hat get to keep it, though they can have it removed upon request if they wish to guess the new trigger.

---

#### Propel Thyself

[image: Propel Thyself]

> Get three other secret hats on one site. *(Hat and trigger from 2018)*

---

#### Rubber Ducky

[image: Rubber Ducky]

> Use the discard button on any ["Ask A Question"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) page, on Meta.SE or a child meta. It can take as much as 3 hours to get. Alternatively, start a draft and wait 7 days for it to be self-deleted. *(Hat and trigger from 2018)*

---

#### 180°

[image: 180°]

> Vote to close a question, be the first to edit the question while it is closed, and vote to reopen it. *(Hat and trigger from 2016)*

---

#### Mother of Dragons

[image: Mother of Dragons]

> Create a first post (question or answer) that after 3 days is +3 or higher.

---

#### Eliza Doolots

[image: Eliza Doolots]

> Earn 2020 rep across the network, excluding association bonus. Hat is awarded on sites where you earn 200+ rep. *(Not confirmed)*
>
>  Hat trigger confirmed by Catija last year [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48358938#48358938).

---

#### Edward Edwards

[image: Edward Edwards]

> Win a bounty where a competing answer has already met the criteria for the bounty to be automatically awarded. *(Hat and trigger from 2015)*

---

Comment: At least one of these definitions is wrong. Just saying...

Comment: @YaakovEllis Can you confirm that the two incorrect triggers, as of the time you posted that comment, have been fixed or removed.

Comment: @David I can confirm that the hat whose description was removed had had the wrong description. And yet, at least one of these descriptions is wrong (well, mostly right, but not 100%)

Comment: @YaakovEllis a random suggestion - once, try to tie an hat to an Easter egg on the Winter Bash site, then have fun seeing how many will even notice it exists.

Comment: @PhishMaster come on over to the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101913/tarnish-web-2019) you're on the right track, but kind of wrong :)

Comment: I just got blue in the face and 007 on Meta, and the triggers do not match with what I have done during the Bash so far.

Comment: How sure are y'all about that new 007 definition?

Comment: @YaakovEllis It's not 007 anymore.

Comment: It seems you don't get "Warm Welcome" for any user's first post, only someone with the "new contributor" banner

Comment: The trigger for Eliza Doolots seems to be wrong. I earned it on a site where I have less than 1300 reputation.

Comment: @wimi you earned it on 3 sites. If you add the rep you got on those 3 sites during winterbash (not including association bonus), you should reach a total >= 2020.

Comment: @Eran that is true, but then why did I not earn it on other sites on which I also got reputation during Winter Bash? And why did I earn it later on Math.SE than on the other two sites? Maybe there is an additional requirement of minimum reputation earned per site...

Comment: @wimi last time this hat appeared (last year), you only got the hat in sites were you earned at least 200 rep during winterbash. If you earned it later on Math.SE, it's possible the first 2 sites were sufficient to reach 2020, and Math.SE was added once you reached +200 rep there.

Comment: @Eran wow, how can you know which hats I earned last year?

Comment: @wimi I have no idea which hats you earned last year.

Comment: I take a screen shot at the end for the Bash each year and can go back to those pics.

Comment: @wimi veteran hatters keep records of things like that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the trigger for 007 is 0 comments on a +7 answer. I triggered this with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59405024/how-to-add-a-dictionary-item-from-one-list-to-the-other-dictionary-in-other-list/59405045#59405045) _after_ the trigger was changed. I'm pretty positive but if someone could confirm or explain why they invalidated my edit, that'd be swell!

Comment: @cs95supportsMonica it's wrong, that is not the trigger (and that is not the answer you earned the hat for). you can come into the c**hat*** room to learn more.

Answer (score 31):

## Common hats for Winter Bash 2019

*Click on each of the hats for a larger image.*

---

#### Scarf Ace

[image: Scarf Ace]

earn the [Guru](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/18/guru) badge

---

#### Glasses With A Number On Top

[image: Glasses With A Number On Top]

starred chat, ±12h from Jan 1, 0:00 UTC
post a message in chat within ±12 hours of the UTC New Year’s begin that gets starred

---

#### Just Jesting

[image: Just Jesting]

10 upvoted comments
post 10 comments that each earn an upvote

---

#### The Milliner

[image: The Milliner]

collect 11 hats

---

#### Hero Of Time

[image: Hero Of Time]

ask at 7pm anywhere
ask a question when it is 7:00 pm in any time zone

---

#### Werewolf Hunter

[image: Werewolf Hunter]

Note: Trigger of hat was modified during WB, see [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340049/retire-werewolf-hunter) for more information. Also works with 3 tag-only edits.

edit 3 old questions on any site
edited 3 questions on any site that were posted more than a year ago

---

#### Rep Hunter

[image: Rep Hunter]

5 accepted answers in 1 day
post 5 answers that get accepted, all posted in a single UTC day or all accepted in a single UTC day

---

#### Cosmic Brain

[image: Cosmic Brain]

earn the [Nice Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer) badge [answer score of 10 or more]

---

#### Fashionable

[image: Fashionable]

9000 views of your questions
get over 9,000 combined total views on all questions that you asked during Winter Bash

---

#### Red Baron

[image: Red Baron]

answer question at -3, becomes +3 and answer +5
answer a question scoring -3 or lower; the question eventually becomes 3+ and your answer becomes 5+

---

#### Foot of the Rainbow

[image: Foot of the Rainbow]

earn a gold badge on any site
earn a gold badge on either a meta or a main site

---

#### Where in the World?

[image: Where in the World?]

post or vote on Dec 21
ask, answer, or vote when it’s December 21st anywhere in the world (this hat comes in two forms, but you can only get one)

---

#### Where in the World?

[image: Where in the World?]

post or vote on Dec 21
ask, answer, or vote when it’s December 21st anywhere in the world (this hat comes in two forms, but you can only get one)

---

#### Snaphat

[image: Snaphat]

answer in 30 min, +3 and accepted
answer within 30 minutes of the question being asked, scoring 3 and getting accepted

---

#### Philantropist

[image: Philantropist]

award bounty on last day
award a bounty, to someone else, on the last day of hats

---

#### Bûche de Noël

[image: Bûche de Noël]

post or vote on December 25th
ask, answer, or vote on December 25th

---

#### Amazing Grace

[image: Amazing Grace]

earn a silver badge on any site
earn a silver badge on either a meta or a main site

---

#### Living in the Future

[image: Living in the Future]

self-answer +5 an old question
self-answer a question you asked before Winter Bash and score +5 on the answer

---

#### Silencium

[image: Silencium]

question with no flags for a week
ask a question that gets no flags within a week of being posted

---

#### Shiver Me Timbers

[image: Shiver Me Timbers]

provide highest scoring answer that outscores accepted answer
provide the highest scoring answer that outscores an already accepted answer having a score of 2 or more, by at least 2

---

Comment: For Werewolf, main meta or any meta?

Comment: @AnkitSharma Mother meta or child Metas. Both will work.

Comment: @NogShine you tested it?

Comment: @AnkitSharma Yeah. I got it on Hinduism meta and there are many who got it here.

Comment: @AnkitSharma There are very, *very* few hats you can only earn only on a single exchange (i.e. when it says "meta" it applies to *any* meta). I can only think of one from a couple years ago and I think they've updated the trigger since.

Comment: Werewold hunter has been [changed to apply to any site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340160).

Comment: Perhaps it should be noted on **Hero Of Time** that you need to ask a *well received* question to get the hat.

Comment: Does 7:00 PM has to be exact or a few seconds after 7:00 PM would give "Hero of the Time" hat?

Comment: @user3306356 no note needed.*All hats* have a [Implicit quality requirement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245123/278094).