# Is there a minimum reputation to obtain hats?

Tags: discussion, reputation, winter-bash-2019

I created this account to answer some questions on Stack Overflow and also to obtain some hats.

I have answered some questions and one of my answers was even accepted and upvoted, but I still haven't earned any hats.

I don't want spoil myself by checking the secret hats and I know some hats requires more goals to achieve, but, I thought at least one hat was possible to get by doing just that.

Thus, due to this being a new account, I think this might be a bug or about my low reputation; so, my question is:

Is there a minimum reputation for obtain hats?

Comment: Seriously though - what is it with people downvoting anything that has to do with the Winter Bash this year?

Comment: @X-27wantstoReinstateMonica I suppose some didn't really want WB to happen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is not. Any logged in user can earn a hat (though for most hats you will end up earning rep in the process of earning the hat).

Answer (score 4):

### No, there is not.

All hats are [listed here](https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/), and there is no hat for an accepted answer with +1 score.

However, there are some unreachable hats for new contributors.

> #### Living in the Future
>
> [image]
>
> self-answer a question you asked before Winter Bash and score +5 on
>   the answer.

You can't earn that because you haven't asked questions here before.

> #### Werewolf Hunter
>
> [image]
>
> edited 3 questions on meta that were posted more than a year ago.

It requires 2,000 reputation points to edit posts on per-site metas, though you can edit community wiki posts with only 100 reputation (easier to earn). Also, you can earn this on Meta Stack Exchange through suggested edits.

There is also one secret hat which you can't earn.

> #### 180°
>
> [image]
>  Vote to close a question, be the first to edit the question while it is closed, and vote to reopen it. Requires 3000 reputation points. Not sure if you manage to do it that fast. You can do this on your own posts with only 250 reputation, but this case is possibly excluded.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Werewolf hunter — "edit 3 old questions on meta". See no difference in the answer )

Comment: Is [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340160/164403) not being documented yet? (Well, my bad. The part that's missing is not implemented yet.)

Answer (score 2):

## Yes and No.

Technically speaking, the lowest your reputation can ever go is 1, so the minimum reputation required is 1. That being said, there is very little that a user can do with 1 reputation, As a matter of practicality though the minimum reputation to get most hats is 11, and getting certain hats require a bit more reputation.

For example, you need 20 reputation to talk in chat, and you need to be able to post a message in chat in order to get the [Glasses With A Number On Top](https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/glasses-with-a-number-on-top) hat. You need at least 75 reputation to start a bounty, and you can't get the [Philantropist](https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/philantropist) hat without setting a bounty.

With no exceptions that I am aware of, for any question or answer to qualify for hats, it needs to be positively scored. For example, consider the [Hero Of Time hat](http://%20Hero%20Of%20Time). You can ask a question right at 7:00, but you might not get the hat until days later, or maybe not at all - you will not get the hat until your question gets to a positive score. (This was most likely put in place years ago to prevent people from spamming no-effort, off-topic garbage to get hats before their posts got deleted, and has stayed as part of the bash since then).

Hats like [Bûche de Noël](https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/b%C3%BBche-de-no%C3%ABl) or [Where in the World?](https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/where-in-the-world) require you to post or vote on December 21st, or 25th, respectively. However, you need 15 reputation to upvote (100 to downvote), and as previously stated, a question or answer needs to be positively scored to qualify for hats - and you would gain 10 reputation from it being upvoted once, bringing your total to 11.

*But it is still possible to earn hats without your single starting reputation point!*

The [Just Jesting](https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/just-jesting) hat requires 10 of your comments posted during the Winter Bash to be upvoted. Having your comments upvoted does not give you reputation, and although you need 5 reputation to comment everywhere, you can comment on your own posts with 1 reputation. So if you ask a question or post an answer (and it receives no upvotes) but you manage to post 10 comments and have them upvoted, you can get a hat without earning any reputation!

#### TL/DR

No - there is no hard reputation minimum for hats in general, but the actions required to earn certain hats can not be performed without the necessary privileges, and you will as a matter of practicality gain reputation in the process of making good contributions and earning hats.

Answer (score 1):

There is no minimum reputation for getting hats.

However, none of [your posts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12511801/marco-aurelio-fernandez-reyes?tab=answers) (right now, this consists of three answers) qualifies for any hats so far. So, there doesn't seem to be any buggy behavior here. If your answer gets up to +10, you'll get a hat.

Many hats don't involve answering at all too.

You can see the qualifications for all the non-secret hats [here](https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/). And you can see the conditions for all the hats [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339891/%ef%b8%8f-winter-bash-2019-hat-list-%ef%b8%8f) (don't worry the secret hat conditions are spoilered.