# Is the Rubber Ducky hat only triggering off of Meta sites?

Tags: bug, winter-bash-2019

However, in practice it seems that the Rubber Ducky hat is only triggering for me when

> I discard a post

on either Meta.SE or on Meta RPG.se, but would not trigger when I did the same on main RPG.se. At least two [other people](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52877435#52877435) have reported similar findings with SO and SU. This is also after waiting up to a full day or more for at least one of the users.

Also, if I recall correctly, there was another hat recently with a bug related to main/meta triggers.

Is this a bug?

Comment: I've discarded multiple questions on main IPS.se and have yet to receive a duck hat

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339894/378211 says upto 3 hours to get that particular secret hat.

Comment: I got the hat here on Meta.SE without delay...

Comment: It definitely comes only when discarding a question on Meta.  I just got 5 Rubber Dickies from discarding meta posts on various sites, but didn't get one even after 12 hours after discarding questions on main sites yesterday.

Comment: I got it fairly quickly on meta.su