# The Blue in the Face hat seems to have the same trigger as 007

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2019

I just got the 007 hat, after posting an answer that got to +7 and both question and answer had no comments.

At the same time I got Blue in the Face hat, whose trigger is yet unknown. It looks like all users who got 007 also have Blue in the Face.

This leads me to ask whether both hats have the same trigger, which doesn't make sense. Is it a bug?

Comment: This is a first hat, which have been secret for so long.

Comment: @Ver Nick what do you mean by first hat? It appeared in a past Winter Bash, but with a trigger already taken by another hat this year (10 upvoted comments)

Comment: I mean the trigger still hasn't been releaved, and this is unique for a secret hat.

Comment: @Ver Nick but the fact the I got it along with 007 just after fulfilling the requirements for 007 suggests they have the same trigger, or that the trigger for blue is a subset of the trigger of 007. This might be a bug.  On the other hand there are other similar cases. There are multiple hats that if you meet their requirements (guru badge, enlightened badge),  you also get a silver badge and meet the silver badge hat (whose name I forgot).

Comment: Multiple hats are possible, you could have received [Shiver me timbers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339892/282094) too, if you beat the accepted answer.

Comment: There's a chance for you triggering different triggers, actually. You could post a comment just after that, or leave an upvote, or just basically anything.

Comment: If It's not the exact same trigger, I would have expected to see some users having blue in the face but not 007 or vica versa.

Comment: We'll look into this further. There seems to have been some mix-up in that we have two different triggers named very different things, but both of those triggers run queries that pull the exact same results. I'd bet it was renamed when the original trigger was reused later, for the exact reason that the original trigger name wasn't clear as to what it did.

Comment: @animuson thanks for the comment. That might explain it.

Comment: @Eran has 007 been the first secret hat you got during 2019's winter bash? I received 007 and "Blue in the face" together, too. And 007 was my first secret hat.

Comment: @dpr no, I got several other secret hats before this pair

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They both have different triggers.

### Update (2019-12-19 12:04 UTC)

So I have to *mea culpa* here. While (as animuson pointed out) I was technically correct that these two secret hats had different triggers, both triggers actually did the same thing: award the hat to someone who posted an answer that got to +7 and both question and answer had no comments.

<sub>(Well, technically speaking they were a tiny bit different in that one of them filtered out questions that were converted to Community Wiki and the other one did not, but practically speaking this didn't make any difference in the hats that were awarded).</sub>

So what to do? Though this isn't breaking any rules (since we make the rules), it isn’t much fun, is it?

#### Here is what is going to happen

1. Both of these "secret" hats (*Blue in the Face* and *007*) are once again secret. As in: they each have a brand new trigger (never been used before)
2. This change is live as of the time posted in this answer (above). So if you got both hats before this answer was posted, it was with the old trigger definition. If you get either hat after this answer was posted, it is with the new trigger definition.
3. Anyone who qualified for these hats with the old trigger definitions can keep them. You earned them, wear them with pride (or don’t wear them, if you don't want to).
4. If you are one of those winter bash sleuths who make it a point to [figure out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339894/51) the definitions of secret hats, and  you already earned these hats (and thus would find it hard to figure the new triggers out), I have a one-time offer for you:

   - Ping me in the [WB 2019 chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101913/tarnish-web-2019-) before this coming Sunday (Dec 22) at 12:00 UTC, with the message "@YaakovEllis please remove my old hats"
   - Sometime after that I will remove the hats from your inventory (and take them off your avatar if you are wearing them). I will post a message in the chat room after this takes place.
   - You may earn one or both of them back right away (if you qualify with the new trigger). Or you may not get them back at all. Don't say I didn't warn you.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this, but the fact that we didn't find any user who only got one of them suggests that the triggers are very similar, or that it's very hard to get one of them without the other.

Comment: This answer doesn't really clarify much.

Comment: @connectyourchargerpartedways Secret trigger is secret.

Comment: @connectyourchargerpartedways It appears there is more to it than what this answer is saying, based on animuson's comment above. We'll have to wait for an update.

Comment: Of these, which specific one excluded CW questions, and which didn't?

Comment: Thanks for the update

Comment: Guess this explains why I just got the "Blue in the Face" hat but not the "007" hat...

Comment: So that is why I just got Blue in the Face!

Comment: Thanks for the both the honest and transparent communication and the quick remediation!

Comment: I received the 007 hat and not the blue in the face hat this morning. I have a rough idea of what the trigger may be.