# Unfitting "This Is Fine" hat

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2019

In light of the turmoil the SE community is in the midst of I see the "*This Is Fine*" hat as (at best) an egregious oversight.

We have a [quote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337910/winter-bash-2019-is-it-happening-this-year#comment1134022_339591) from one of the new WB devs

> "...not enough bandwidth here to make a brand new theme... (Mostly) different hats and missions."

Someone went through and chose the hats for this year. Even if the hats are all reused they are not just a copy from last year, the "This Is Fine" hat was last seen in 2017.

Knowing that, I can not fathom how SE felt it was ok to run a hat that says "This Is Fine."

I feel "This Is **Not** Fine" and this hat, under the current circumstances is inappropriate.

There is no hiding the fact that the community is very much upset. We are not Fine. The situation with Monica is not Fine. Our relationship with you SE is not Fine. The name for this hat is not Fine.

---

I'm perfectly "fine" with the trigger but really feel you all should of used a different hat name. The "*Just Here for the Hat*" from [2016](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288272/278094) would have made a great image.
Something like:

#### Consolation Prize

[image: Just Here for the Hat from 2016]

> Answer a bountied question and receive an upvote, but not the bounty. Answer must be posted during the bounty period but not necessarily during Winterbash.

Comment: I might be missing something here, but isn't the ["This Is Fine" meme](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/this-is-fine) about things _not_ being fine? I think it's pretty fitting...

Comment: Yeah, I kinda feel like that hat is evergreen.

Comment: I'm upvoting this post as there's nothing wrong with the content.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### You seem to be missing the point of that meme

According to [KnowYourMeme](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/this-is-fine):

> The comic, depicts a dog in a room that is burning to the ground. The dog reacts calmly, even as he slowly melts from the heat.

The whole point of that comic is that things are *not* fine. The title and quote are, I think, an example of situational irony. It's not really fair to criticize only the title of the comic devoid from the entire context of the comic itself (which is relatively well-known).

In fact, I've seen that meme used many times in chat and comments by community members to describe this whole situation. Far from an egregious oversight, it actually seems arguably very fitting in some respects.

It's fine.

Comment: So this is another situation where my lack of knowledge on the things of the internet, in this case memes, causes me to look stupid... I agree, if you know memes then yeah this totaly fits.

Comment: Ironically, there's a sequel, because [things are not fine](https://thenib.com/this-is-not-fine).