# Winter Bash has ended, but the hats metadata still seems to be available

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

Winter Bash 2020 has ended, but I discovered an old Stack Overflow tab from a few days earlier which still had the snowflake hats icon on top.  To my surprise, when I clicked it, I still got my list of hats:

[image: screen capture showing Winter Bash hats]

I verified that the page was not stale, as I checked my reputation tab from the same page and got back today's data.  Also, when I clicked the opt out of hats button, I got an error.

Can someone explain this observations?  Is the endpoint for fetching hats metadata still up and running?

Comment: They should make a hat for clicking on the snowflake tab after Winter Bash has ended.  Hat to be awarded at the start of Winter Bash 2021.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen two hats. First one "anticip" awarded at the time you clicked the snowflake and the second one called "pation" at the next Winter Bash.

Comment: I saw the same behaviour - that tab still had my hat on as well. Then I accidentally caused it to refresh... :(

Comment: How is this a bug? Was there some requirement somewhere that they retire the hat endpoint on a certain schedule? Or that the snowflake be retroactively removed from all browser-cached screens somehow? *Frickin' snowflakes want their snowflakes on a schedule now...* :)

Comment: Why can't winterbash last forever? BOO HOOO :((((((

Comment: Can you send us the link on the snowflake. Maybe even we can use it.

Comment: @Shadowcoder There is no "link."  Just find an old tab, at least 3 days old, and then click on the snowflake icon.  You might also be able to back navigate some number of times from your current tab to get it back.

Comment: Caching? :D Its always caching....

Answer (score 7):

The WB site is still up and running. All of the display logic of rendering the snowflake menu, hat switcher, adding hats to pics, as well as the jobs related to awarding hats are off.

If you want to keep your tab open for a few months and keep on reloading the snowflake menu, more power to you.

> winter bash is done
> not however API
> some endpoints still work

Comment: Thanks for this insightful answer, Jake +1.

Comment: When will the Winter Bash site be taken down and replaced with a redirect to the SO Contests site page?

Comment: @sonic we normally take the old site down as first step in setting up the new site, sometime around October-ish

Comment: No doubt that tidbit of info, released to Sonic,  will find its way in a FAQ edit.

Comment: @Mari-LouA [It's not exactly new information.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321578/will-the-winter-bash-2018-site-be-available-all-year)