# Winter Bash 2019 Knitting

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, fun, winter-bash-2019

Repost of [Winter Bash 2018 Knitting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319846/358161)

Just go [here](https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/) and click Start Knitting!

Share your knits in the answers.

Comment: should be recycle this too :D

Comment: Please note: I added a brush and added many more colors to the palette for this year - hopefully that will aid in adding some more variety for your knitting.

Comment: @YaakovEllis so there *is* a Winter Bash **2019** Knitting site? Where is it? Is it disabled for those who said "I hate hats"?

Comment: @Mari-LouA go to https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/ and click _Start Knitting_

Comment: @curious You need only to rotate your smartphone. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339936/how-do-i-start-winterbash-knitting-on-mobile

Comment: @CodyGray Argh. I tried rotating only after activating the desktop site it seems (which didn't work, obviously). I did most of my submission on mobile in portrait mode O_o

Comment: If someone knit me a Monica-reminding hat I would "wear" it.

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezjXs.png

Comment: @VerNicksaysReinstateMonica: That's a nice initiative, but I don't think you would see anything other than the hat if I scaled it down to fit on my avatar's head.

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica [This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2475129/manassehkatz-reinstate-monica) for example just loaded it as an avatar :)

Comment: @VerNicksaysReinstateMonica: It [doesn't work that well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19596300/reportlab-image-link) even as their whole avatar :-(

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica Well, they still can see "reinstate Monica" in your username

Answer (score 193):

[image]

Comment: I was going to do this, you beat me to it! :)

Comment: I was wondering if I would see Monica here somewhere!

Comment: [Seems I actually beaten you both, @X-27](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52508024#52508024). But I like this version more.

Comment: You even did antialiasing, nice! :)

Answer (score 173):

No description needed :)

[image: Monica]

Comment: Where's the appropriate help desk so I can file a complaint about a "*[copycat knitter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338439/359002)*" (just kidding @X-27 ^^)

Comment: @OldPadawan You can direct all complaints to Twitter. That is the most likely communication channel to get an immediate response. (in all seriousness, I had not seen your version, but looking at it now though, it is interesting you used white as the facial highlight. I had tried that, but given that there was only one remotely-skintone color, I opted for an entirely tan face).

Comment: And hey, it works, you made the leaderboard! "Monica" forever, at least for people coming back and looking at that.

Answer (score 105):

Tribute to the [fallen diamonds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper)

[image: Tribute to the 23 resigned moderators]

Comment: Far over the misty mountains cold / To dungeons deep and caverns old / We must away ere break of day / To find our long-forgotten gold  / 
The pines were roaring on the height / The winds were moaning in the night / The fire was red, it flaming spread / The trees like torches blazed with light

Answer (score 81):

I found this secret hat

[image]

today I found a new secret hat, not happy...

[image]

Comment: Cool @Vickel haha

Comment: Looks a lot like [my Reinstate Monica hat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44sVA.png) :)

Comment: What’s in the brown area?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm its a little chapel at the sea

Comment: found another secret hat today....

Answer (score 70):

I have my drawing tablet this year...

[image]
it's meeee with *red eyes*

[image]
Human Stack Exchange/Overflow twins I thought of last year

[image]
Two more characters of my own creation.

[image]
Guess who? (I tried, really I did, but I'm not the best at real people)

I made a thing today, (one of the characters from above) and wanted to make it in the knitting so...grayscale!
[image]
(not my best work but...it'll do)

Original made today for reference:

[image: Reverse Daymare by Eleeza]

*<sub>Oh dear, my prince, what have I done to you?</sub>*

Thanks to the help from Hitodama and ArtOfCode, I was finally able to get the userscript working and made this from a picture I haven't finished yet:

[image]

<sub>Two young royal school students, trapped in a storage cupboard by their enemies, waiting in the harsh winter draft for someone to let them out.</sub>

Original for comparison: (downsized)

[image]

It's me again :D plus lights experiment

[image]

I'll be making more...don't worry. :)

Comment: Thank you :D They were actually inspired by the Winter Bash, with their hats and the scarf

Comment: Very nice. I struggling to draw a face and you managed to get twins.

Comment: Well to be fair, it’s taking a while to make my third knitting...

Comment: Ok, that's just seriously impressive

Comment: You should make different answers so that we could upvote more than once :D

Comment: @Bel, nope, that would backfire very quickly. Updates to a single answer is the way to go, trust me.

Comment: Wow, your knitting skills are amazing!

Comment: [Your knitting design got a (well-deserved) shout-out in the blog.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/01/15/winter-persists-but-winter-bash-2019-has-drawn-to-a-close/)

Comment: Now that really warms my heart <3

Answer (score 56):

In honor of the one who got this hat first last year.

> <sub><sup><sub>Monica Cellio</sub></sup></sub>

#### The Eliza Doolots hat

[image: Eliza Doolots hat knitted]

Answer (score 56):

[image: SE logo embedded in a broken heart + "Do Better In 2020"]

Answer (score 45):

Little bit of outrun.

[image: knitted art of sun on a purple sky]

Answer (score 43):

[image: knitting of a familiar desktop background]

Answer (score 43):

Who's this?

[image: Monica]

Comment: The most unfortunate SE user.

Comment: Yup correct....

Comment: First user to earn Eliza Doolots hat last year.

Answer (score 40):

### **Farewell, my Friend**

Picture taken from [Made in Abyss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Made_in_Abyss), EP. 13. Original for comparison [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O45kf.jpg)

[image: Made in Abyss - knitting]

---

---

### **Do you remember your fear of the dark?**

From the game Yomawari: Midnight Shadows. Original for comparison [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDr3R.jpg)

[image: Yomawari]

---

---

### **A girl and a shadow**

From the manga "The girl from the other side". Sadly Shiva is very pale, has very whitish hairs and wears a white dress. So, sorry if she looks like a white blob. As for Teacher.. he is supposed to look that way.

[image: Siúil, a Rún]

---

---

### **End of an age** (also know as Executive Meddling 101)

Picture taken from the Megaman Zero saga ending. A cracked helmet in the sand, salvation came at a price.

[image: An hat in the sand]

---

---

### **And this is only 0.2% of my true power**

Many users still believe that Ultra Instinct was something Dragonball Super introduced... Wrong! Shaggy obviously mastered it far before Goku poor attempts.

[image: The original Ultra Instinct]

---

---

### **I see a path not meant to be**

Taken from [REDACTED]. We will meet again in about a year.

[image: Your choice was made]
(bonus: [alternate version...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/av33T.png))

---

Note: all the knitting here were done using a custom color palette. They won't work for you unless you use the same color palette I use.
For more info refer to [this message in the Tavern chat room](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8109015#8109015).

Comment: +1 for better artistic talent than me :-)

Comment: But what *is* it?

Comment: @ChrissaysReinstateMonica  you are right, added the source and the original picture for comparison.

Comment: Was this done using any sort of script or are you a magician?

Comment: @Eleeza as for the colors palette, please refer to the message I linked in the reply. I started with that user script and added more color as needed.As for the pictures, you can load any picture in the tool, provided it has the correct size.... Obviously, the automatic import isn't that great, so you usually have to do some fixes afterward... but it is a start.

Comment: [Your knitting design got a (well-deserved) shout-out in the blog.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/01/15/winter-persists-but-winter-bash-2019-has-drawn-to-a-close/)

Answer (score 39):

Christmas Tux

[image: Christmas Tux]

Comment: Did you do this by hand?

Comment: @JL2210-SupportMonica Not totally, I used a pixelated image of Tux as a starting point but I altered it a bit and I did the hat and presents.

Answer (score 35):

My version of [Cybertruck](https://www.tesla.com/cybertruck):

[image: Cybertruck-SouravGhosh]

Comment: the windows seem... intact

Comment: @JourneymanGeek That's because I did not dare to throw anything at...may laptop screen. :)

Answer (score 32):

Always remember to recycle, like the questions

[image]

Comment: What goes around meta, comes around meta...

Answer (score 30):

[image: The great wave]

No special meaning, just seemed like the right color palette.

<sub>Hopefully Hokusai doesn't DMCA this... ;D</sub>

Comment: Does this Belong to [California Games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_Games)?

Answer (score 30):

[image: Stack Exchange Inc. is wrong. cutt.ly/se_is_wrong]

Answer (score 30):

[image]

*"You shall not tell my boss I just spent 30 minutes knitting this on Stack Exchange!"*

Answer (score 27):

The Simpsons - "[A Totally Fun Thing That Bart Will Never Do Again](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Totally_Fun_Thing_That_Bart_Will_Never_Do_Again)" - S23E19

[Bart Simpson](https://simpsons.fandom.com/wiki/Bart_Simpson) being chased by (left to right): [Kearney Zzyzwicz](https://simpsons.fandom.com/wiki/Kearney_Zzyzwicz), [Dolph Starbeam](https://simpsons.fandom.com/wiki/Dolph_Starbeam) and [Jimbo Jones](https://simpsons.fandom.com/wiki/Jimbo_Jones).

[image: The Simpsons - S23E19]

Comment: You forgot the eyes..

Comment: You are back with gifs! ;)

Comment: @NogShine - Yes. Since they were enormously popular last year, even receiving special mention on the SO.blog,  I thought everyone would appreciate seeing one.

Answer (score 27):

[image]

Answer (score 26):

[image]

Answer (score 23):

[image: Transgender flag in knitting]

The transgender flag.

Comment: +1 My favourite sweater used to look kind of like this. Never knew it’s become a flag.

Comment: This never struck me on the actual flag, but on this knit, I can't help seeing retro CGA graphics. It is exactly the same cyan/pink colors, and the knits look like the huge pixels of a 320x200 screen. +1 for the memories.

Answer (score 23):

I used to get a lot of compliments on my gravitar. That's why I asked @Avazula to incorporate it into my current avatar! (Sorry, my knitting skills aren't good enough to get my new avatar on there)

[image: Rainbacon]

I got to wondering how it would look as a fractal. Sadly I could only make one more layer before it got too pixelated and the shapes went away.

[image]

Comment: I like the selfie knittings

Answer (score 22):

I can never have enough rainbows so...

[image]

And snow for those living in the northern hemisphere:

[image]

My previous year's submission:

[image]

Comment: Hmm... It seems a few people don't like our [rainbows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339926/395288). I wonder why not.

Comment: @SuperJade, meh. Average downvote count on rainbows (right now): -4. Average downvote count on Monica: -7. This was bound to happen. Divisive answers are divisive, nothing we can do about that.

Comment: What's divisive about rainbows?

Comment: What's divisive about Monica's avatar?

Comment: Maybe they don’t like [Cusco, Peru](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Cusco).

Comment: It could have been a [double rainbow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Double-alaskan-rainbow.jpg). Note that the order of the colors is reversed (unlike that medieval painter that got it wrong (I can't find the reference now)).

Answer (score 21):

Did you know that 2020 is the Year of the Rat according to Chinese zodiac?

[image]

Comment: Yup! [Frank, Dean and Sammy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rat_Pack) had told me :D

Answer (score 20):

This is intended to be an exact replica of the knit that is present on the Winter Bash 2019 screen before you start knitting.

It took me more than half an hour; the distortion caused by the screenshot caused most of the right half of the knit to be distorted, and the restoration process was tedious. Please let me know if I made any mistakes; I'll be glad to fix them.

[image: Winter Bash 2019]

<sup>Edit 1: I missed a light blue pixel in 9 that should've been white.</sup>

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: It would be better to change 2019 to 2020.

Comment: @VerNicksaysReinstateMonica This is intended to be an exact replica of the one shown when you first load the page before you start knitting.

Comment: Oh, okay then, didn't notice it was 2019 at first.

Comment: It is probably more useful than playing (mindless) computer games.

Comment: "_distortion_ caused by the screenshot" - Errrm, how did you do your screenshot??

Comment: @MrWhite I took the original from the first screen and I took a screenshot by hand (essentially like the snipping tool on Windows). There's no way to save the one from the first time you load the page correctly. From there I had to resize it and that's where a lot of the distortion came from. After that I filled in the pixels that were missing or had the wrong color and I came up with this.

Answer (score 17):

The big-eyed owl :D

[image: Owl]

Comment: Not my species! ([Strix aluco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tawny_owl) [aluco](https://www.owlpages.com/owls/species.php?s=1580))

Answer (score 16):

[image]

That is the SE mod symbol, that ones that goes on the mod hats, against a rainbow background. Knitting based on my own hat.

Drawn entirely by hand, including the background.

Answer (score 16):

Tried my best:

[image]

Comment: Fastest Dved post award goes to my answer :D

Comment: What the hell is going on around here? Any post gets downvoted.

Answer (score 15):

[image]

Answer (score 15):

With the [famous series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_of_Thrones) coming to an end, a remembrance:

> *Winter is (still) coming!!*

[image: nedstark-knit]

Comment: North remembers!

Answer (score 15):

Have we been good this year Santa?

[image: Thumbs Up Santa]

Comment: Looks more like FoxTrot.

Answer (score 15):

Poor penguin.. He's alone in the snow for Christmas :(

[image: Penguin]

Comment: It is summer in the Southern Hemisphere (where [penguins live](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penguin)), so it can only be in [Antarctica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antarctica) (cold enough). Or perhaps some high mountain ranges (but will you find penguins there?).

Comment: @PeterMortensen It is winter on Stack Exchange too :)

Comment: Good point. I think penguins live in Antarctica.... I don't know XD

Answer (score 14):

[image: 2019 trans symbole and gay flag]

I'll let you guess the "hidden" flag ^^

---

And here is a gif showing how the knitting was done:

[image: Gif representing the making of the knitting]

Comment: You're a much more organized knitter than I am.

Comment: @SuperJade To be honest, I had a very hard time drawing that first circule and was terrified to make an edit and lose it. Thus, all the savings ^^

Answer (score 13):

Minimal :D

[image]

Comment: Every developer's right of passage. :-)

Comment: HELLO EARID !! ;)

Comment: HELLO, iLuvLogix 7 ;) :)

Comment: It is [missing a comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program).

Comment: It is pronounced "Hello, World!\n"

Answer (score 12):

[image: The White House]

Comment: Why isn't it on fire?

Comment: 1814 was a long time ago.

Comment: @visibleman fixed that!

Comment: @visibleman They surrender!

Comment: But where [is the princess](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-too-intrusive/1974#1974)?

Answer (score 12):

A visionary, a genius, ensuring freedom around the world. Spoilers added to not ruin the fun for anyone who hasn't seen the movie yet :)

> [image]

Comment: by expired link ?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQXPg.png

Comment: Who is it?......

Comment: Am I the only one who thought it was Thanos?

Comment: @PeterMortensen That's Tony Stark...

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Hehe don't see any purple on the gif...

Comment: [Tony Stark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Stark_(Marvel_Cinematic_Universe)) (fictional character)

Answer (score 12):

Every year we learn something new!
This year 2k19 (2019) has taught me a lot of new things! Thank you 2k19. Ak19 is gonna miss you! :(

A few months before, my friend asked me whether I'd change my name as "Ak20", by the year 2020. :P
[image]

> Well! Welcome 2k20!!!

Answer (score 12):

Sparkles the unicorn!

[image: Unicorn]

Answer (score 11):

Who is this?

> U10-Forward

[image: Me]

Comment: Great selfie knitting!

Answer (score 11):

[image]

Comment: Grundy will never change :)

Answer (score 11):

For all 49ers fans!!!
How do you get it?

The 49ers HelmHat<sup>™</sup> rewards any Q with (any of the following):

- 49 UV
- 49 answers ^^
- 49 favorite questions stars
- 49$ given to any charity

[image]

---

@Pikoh : for a very fair player/user, and according to our "*be nice*" policy, I'm pleased to offer you our brand new 2020 *Winterbash Seahawks Hat™* as an update. Happy Holidays! (to ya'll)

[image]

Comment: Is this a real hat? (real as in Stack Exchange real).

Comment: @SuperJade: I wish!!! Big 49ers fan here, you bet I'd *love* it :)

Comment: While not *my* team, I can't help but feel happy for the 49ers to finally come out of their years long hole this season and for Garoppolo to finally be able to show his worth after last year's unfortunate injury and after the Patriots threw him away as a Brady successor. So definitely a +1!

Comment: @ChrissaysReinstateMonica : yeah, some happy and some sad years during the Colin K's era and "*the event*"...

Comment: As a Seahawks fan I was tempted to downvote this...but it is a great job. Upvoted :)

Comment: Wow thank you very much! Very kind of you, you are an artist  ;)

Comment: After their recent performance, I'm pretty sure they've been re-named the Seachickens.

Comment: @mark : ouch! That hurts! Let's say that big hit is @ pikoh 's welcome to the NFL :)

Comment: @Mark it was just a bad day at work...we still have our chances ;)

Comment: What are "49ers"?

Comment: @petermortensen: forty-niners are the San Francisco football team, the name is tied to the history of the state of California and 1849 (the gold rush, the name of the diggers...etc [read more](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_Gold_Rush)

Comment: @Pikoh : *rendez-vous* on Monday 30th ;) that won't be 11 out of 12, end of the streak! Happy New Year and GG.

Comment: @OldPadawan hope it would be a thrilling game and the best wins! Happy new year to you ;)

Comment: @Pikoh: yees! They did it, end of the streak :) you'll make it again the Eagles, shouldn't be a problem, we'll see you later maybe?... HNY

Comment: @OldPadawan it was a good game,we could have won in the end ;) Maybe we'll meet again,who knows. Happy new year!

Answer (score 11):

## Just a winter landscape ...

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Narwhals are my favorite! So I knitted one. Btw, the background took half an hour.

[image]

Comment: Lucky you drew your narwhal before you acquired that hat that hides the tusk ;-)

Comment: [Winner winner chicken dinner](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/01/15/winter-persists-but-winter-bash-2019-has-drawn-to-a-close)! (I only have the expression from [Dave Jones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_L._Jones_(video_blogger)) (Mr. EEVBlog).)

Answer (score 11):

Inspired by the [Graphic Design Stack Exchange (GDSE)](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com) logo and background pattern.

[image]

And one a bit more christmassy:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Inspired by a beautiful [piece of art](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339896/winter-bash-2019-knitting/340082#340082) by @iLuvLogix that reminded me of hours spent playing (both games amongst many others), I knitted this one. Can you remember/guess? If needed, hint is below...

> <sub>Samus Aran ([Super Metroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samus_Aran))</sub>

---

[image]

Answer (score 10):

[image]

... and certainly than having a correct grammar

Answer (score 10):

Showing my age..

[image]

Comment: [Commodore PET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commodore_PET)?

Comment: Accidentally, it seems so yes!  I didn't have a specific model in mind, but was thinking of all kinds of green-glowing beauties from my formative years.

Answer (score 10):

Aww... cotton candy met his crwush.

[image: Bunny]

Answer (score 10):

A storm is coming...

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Go to the new year?

[image: Go to the new year?]

Comment: 2019 has [been](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bloodied#Adjective) [bloodied](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pPJf8KrvJXU&t=1m6s).

Answer (score 9):

Don't need anything:

[image]

Comment: [You're too late](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339897/403480) :D

Comment: @VerNicksaysReinstateMonica I know

Answer (score 9):

[image]

This is my pathetic attempt to knit my profile picture, which happens to be a photo of my youngest son when he was a baby. At least I got the Stack Overflow onesie (almost) right.

Answer (score 8):

[image: hisssssSSSSSSSSSS]

What's that hissing sound?

Comment: Hissssssssssssss... BOOM.

Comment: Creeper aw man.

Answer (score 8):

People were knitting on different topics. I made a random one:[image: Random Knitting]

Since this is random therefore you can use your imagination to see in it whatever you want!

Comment: The middle is Stack Exchange and the rest of us are in orbit around it, unable to escape?

Answer (score 8):

Keep calm and earn hats.

[image]

Comment: A sarcastic statement?

Comment: @PeterMortensen This is one of those variations of "[Keep Calm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keep_Calm_and_Carry_On)" quotes. Nothing political.

Answer (score 8):

An adaptation of [this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/118423/63979).

[image: Winter Mountains]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Merry Christmas]

Merry Christmas

Answer (score 8):

Too many lights this year!
[image]

Answer (score 8):

### Title: The future of (Meta?) Stack Exchange!

Inspired by [Pierre Soulages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Soulages) and the continuous efforts of SE Inc. to make this place a different place.

[image: allblack]

(and yes, Soulages uses *different* kinds of black paint, alas, not available to me here)

Comment: Basically just [jdrupal's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340102/256180) with a different colour.

Comment: @faintsignal But the point of view is totally different. Isn't that what art is about?! But sure, that other user got my upvote, too.

Comment: Totally opaque? Or fog of war?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Just black, the blacked black that you can knit with.

Answer (score 7):

Last year's knitting was a [Unicorn at Night](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319863/395288).

This year's knitting is titled "Moonbow":

[image: rainbow at night = Moonbow]

Answer (score 7):

Amazing how nobody didn't come with a coffee yet... So, here is the Love Coffee!

[image: Love Coffee]

Answer (score 7):

I'm not the best at knitting in winter bash, but here is my knitting!

[image: Lonely tree]

Answer (score 7):

Fireworks are very difficult, even with a larger palette. After several tries I'm not as close as I'd like. Here's [where it started](https://youtu.be/g364DaTblYc?t=680) (Akagawa Fireworks Festival 2019), and here's the master and the result:

[image: master]

[image: sweater]

Comment: At least you can tell what it is.

Comment: check this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/321303/251777 happy new year

Answer (score 7):

Jo Jo the hamster.
[image: hamster]

Answer (score 6):

Because it's still the best and most festive colour to ever exist.

[image]

Comment: And highly visible!

Comment: That's my favourite colour too :D Orange works at any time.

Comment: If I could've gotten five upvotes for doing *this*, I would've done it a long time ago. All you have to do is use the bucket tool. No effort!

Comment: We're not doung it for the votes, but for the colour! If you want votes, generate one of these artificial GIFs. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

[image]

That background took an hour.

The rest I slightly cheated and then had to fix it up a bit.

Comment: You,  [Samuel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339924/395288), and [I](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339926/395288) should form a band.

Comment: There [are](http://traffic.libsyn.com/theamphour/TheAmpHour-257-AnInterviewWithFabienneOfKnitYak.mp3) [generative](https://theamphour.com/257-an-interview-with-fabienne-serriere-of-knityak/) [ways](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/fbz/knityak-custom-mathematical-knit-scarves/).

Answer (score 6):

Greetings from [ROMANIA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romania)!

**[La multi ani 2020!](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/la_mul%C8%9Bi_ani)**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

From

> [Nepal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nepal)

[image]

---

<sub>Not a perfect knitting but I steal some office time for this.</sub>

Comment: They even have instruction how to draw it in their constitution - at least according to this Numberphile episode https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2Gne3UHKHs&t=39

Answer (score 5):

A tasty(?!) burger...

[image: Burger Stack]

Comment: Looks fattening

Comment: @JL2210-SupportMonica It's "meat-free" if that helps?!

Answer (score 4):

### The northern lights

[image: Aurora]

Had to posterize the colors by hand. Moderately successful.
[Original NASA image](https://mediaassets.lex18.com/cordillera-network/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2019/05/11075859/nasa.jpg).

Tried using the user script that adds additional colors, but couldn't get it to work for me.

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't going to wear a hat, but then they offered me this irresistible Grace Hopper hat. :D[image: META 2021]

Comment: No, the 2021 part is not a mistake. :)

Answer (score 3):

**Double Thumbs Up Nerd**

[image: Nerd with double thumbs up]

Comment: [Nerds vs. wambs](https://twitter.com/s8mb/status/1204075284309434374)

Answer (score 3):

Who created this hat last year?

> <sup><sup><sup>Monica Cellio</sup></sup></sup>

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Comment: [Flag of India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_India).

Comment: with troll face

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Comment: Why all the down votes?

Answer (score 0):

Hatted Gwen Stefani - [What You Waiting For?](https://youtu.be/f5qICl3Fr3w?t=128)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: A waterspout with flowers growing on it]

Answer (score 0):

[image: :D]

Answer (score 0):

My first ever knitting in 3 years :)

[Just my pictorial representation of Cesar’s speedy solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340579/378211)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Comment: Corresponding "[Grammar Girl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammar_Girl%27s_Quick_and_Dirty_Tips_for_Better_Writing)" (yes, that is her own invention) podcast episode: [episode 206](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/is-im-loving-it-proper-grammar)

Comment: It's lovin' it.

Comment: @JL2210-SupportMonica, Grundy too conservative for that :)