# How do I start Winterbash knitting on mobile?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2019

As we know, the theme of this year Winter Bash is knitting. [There is already a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339896/357396) to submit our knitting designs.

How do I start knitting using a mobile device? Is this feature available on mobile devices?

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but is this question supposed to be here? Should it not be on https//crafts.stackexchange.com? I am confused.

Comment: @ChrisRogers I am asking about Knitting theme which is specific to Winterbash 2019.

Comment: Downvoters seems confused.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I didn't see the 'Start Knitting' button either:

[image]

until I tried to rotate the device to landscape. Then, the button appeared:

[image]

and, unsurprisingly,

[image: it works!]

Comment: Makes sense. Auto rotate was turned off on my mobile.

Comment: Makes sense. I have to do the rotation dance to close questions on mobile, too…

Answer (score 17):

When I built the knitting editor last year, I decided there has to be a minimum width for knitting to make sense, and the value I picked happens to be between typical widths and heights of common phone screens, so it may often work in landscape but not portrait mode.

<sub>Please keep Glorfindel's answer accepted but give me upvotes so I can get the *Shiver Me Timbers*. Pretty please?</sub>

Comment: Have you considered rejoining the company as a temporary employee every year, whenever it's time for Winter Bash?

Comment: @Sonic What's the going hourly rate for Digital Hat Consultants?

Comment: 100 magical unicorn points per hour, last time I checked. Maybe they can just grant you code checkin privileges every year around end of November. What could go wrong? :-)

Comment: wow. Because of all the hat haters you got the red baron. :) One of the harder ones... Thanks again @balpha, always fun. (PS just gave you the Shiver Me Timbers hat)

Answer (score 4):

I found another way to start knitting.

[Winterbash2019](https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/) is in responsive design such that the mobile phone screen mode by default when used on mobile devices.

[image: Screenshot of Winterbash site on mobile]

Select menu button in your browser app. Select 'Desktop site'. This will show you full site and 'Start Knitting' option in portrait mode.

[image: Screenshot of Winterbash site in desktop mode showing 'Start Knitting' option]