# Knitting on mobile missing some colours

Tags: bug, mobile-web, winter-bash, winter-bash-2019, knitting

I asked a question how to start knitting on Winterbash site.

[How do I start Winterbash knitting on mobile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339936/357396). One answer gave a way to use in landscape mode. It worked. But some colours are cropped out.

[image]

[balpha's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340014/357396) says:

> When I built the knitting editor last year, I decided there has to be a minimum width for knitting to make sense, and the value I picked happens to be between typical widths and heights of common phone screens

When we used landscape mode, 6 colours are cropped out (3 from left and 3 from right). Desktop version has more colours.

[image]

Browser version :  79.0.3945.79
Screen size : 6 inches.

Since there are 2 weeks left in Winterbash, can mobile version also get all colours?

Comment: what is your screen resolution?

Comment: FYI, you can start knitting at 641px wide, and can only see the full pallete at 975px wide. Don't know if I will have time to fix it…

Comment: @Yaakov My screen resolution is 393x786.

Comment: For the record, last year had a lot fewer colors, this wasn't an issue in 2018.

Answer (score 1):

I have an extremely small phone but I was able to get the entire palette by zooming out with the <sub>A</sub>A control thing (the phone also must be in landscape):

[image]

(This is Safari on iPhone SE. Hopefully something similar will work for you.)

Comment: I tried different methods to show all colours. 1. [Enabling desktop site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340131/357396) i.e disabling responsiveness  . 2. Your method. My browser on Android phone doesn't have zooming in option  but after overriding zoom out, I tried to see 3 more colours. Still some colours are missing. My question is about the site with responsiveness enabled. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @NogShine Does this [comment conversation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337910/winter-bash-2019-is-it-happening-this-year/339591#comment1135905_339591) assist with the problem outlined in your [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340626/knitting-on-mobile-missing-some-colours#comment1138431_340633) directly above? --- Short (long?) version: #1: Android phone, FF. #2: Enable Mobile view (in browser). #3 Choose "Full Site" (lower right webpage). #4: Enable Desktop view (in browser). #5: Read 1st link in this comment. #6: See screenshots there. --- My phone is 3K screen.