# Chat still shows the old Warm Welcome hat

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, winter-bash, winter-bash-2019

Yesterday the star on the `Warm Welcome` hat was changed to a heart, according to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340512/this-star-on-the-warm-welcome-hat-looks-like-a-communist-symbol).

But it seems like `chat.stackexchange.com` has not been updated yet.

[image]

I see the new hat on my profile, but not on chat.

Is this a bug, or is chat just a bit slow to recognize the change?

Comment: There are also other sporting this now retired design, should we blame 6-8 week caching?

Comment: Pretty sure it's not cache, and chat takes a different copy of the SVG, which  wasn't updated.

Comment: can you please link me to someone in chat in a public room wearing the hat?

Comment: @YaakovEllis Here it is, https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/327/drupal-answers.

Comment: @YaakovEllis It's also showing me with the old hat in that chatroom. I've just re-equipped the new hat - so it's not just for people who were wearing the hat before the change (if helpful).

Comment: No hats on mobile chat btw

Comment: Also JNat is sporting one in the tavern.

Comment: @Luuklag there are no hats at all on mobile...

Comment: @YaakovEllis No all hat's are gone on mobile.

Comment: were they ever there?

Comment: @YaakovEllis I don't think so.

Comment: @YaakovEllis, I usually use the responsive design on mobile, but for Chat that doesn't appear to be an option. Hence I wouldn't know.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Hats on chat should be up to date now.

It was a caching issue. Or maybe an off-by-one error. Well, one of those three things anyway.

Comment: Cool, thanks for taking time to look at it :)

Comment: Kudos for continuing [company tradition](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/506010907021828096) :)

Comment: Once again, [blame cache](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/) :D

Comment: @MEE so true, Yaakov is a worthy successor of Jeff. If only he'll get to Jeff's original position at SE, things will be so much better.