# What does the picture of "Warm Welcome" hat represent?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

I hope, that the question fits here.

What does the picture of **Warm Welcome** hat represent? (I am not asking about the meaning of the hat, but the image itself.)

[image: Warm Welcome hat]

**EDIT:** It turned out to be an usánka.

Comment: Per the answer to [This star on the Warm Welcome hat looks like a communist symbol](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340512/this-star-on-the-warm-welcome-hat-looks-like-a-communist-symbol): it's intended to evoke "a feeling of welcome".

Comment: As per [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339891/824803) it is offered when you upvote someone's first post. So, it means you are a amiable person, kind person, encouraging person.... :)

Comment: I don't mean the meaning of the hat, I am asking about the image itself.

Comment: It's an [ushanka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ushanka), made to keep your ears and face warm. Why the Stack Exchange team wants to associate upvotes with "welcoming" is and has always been a mystery to me.