# Three Polymath notifications - from 3 questions, or 9?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2016

I got three notifications about hats today:

[image]

Does this mean I earned the hat once, for well-received answers on those three sites, or three times, for well-received answers on 9 sites?

Comment: The behavior is the same for *Running Ragged* too. And when later you post a well-received answer on another site, you will get Polymath on that site too. Same for Running Ragged.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You got it for having at least one good answer on those sites. So if you have 1 good answer on each = Polymath. So that's 3 answers. The hat is awarded simultaneously for the three sites.

I have this on <s>4</s> *5* sites, for having at least one answer scoring at least 1 on each site. Like on ELU, I only had one answer, yet I received the hat.

[image: hat list]

Comment: Not necessarily simultaneously. I got the notification for two sites in one hat run and the third site on the next run.

Comment: @MartinSmith Huh. That's odd. That may be a bug :P

Comment: Maybe just a race condition if you become eligible during the hat run?

Answer (score 3):

This means you earned the hat once because you had a well received answer on The Workplace, Personal Productivity, and Travel. The hat is awarded on all 3 sites in which you had a well received answer.

For example, if I had a well received answer on SuperUser, Meta Stack Exchange, and Travel, I would get 3 hat notifications because I got the hat *once*, but it was awarded to me on the 3 sites where I had the well received answer.

Comment: You were ninja'd :P

Comment: @Mithrandir dang. Typing on mobile is hard.

Comment: @Mithrandir You mean [Skeeted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts)... in a way