# Voting buttons for locked posts

Tags: discussion, support, voting, locked-questions

I noticed that voting for [locked question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites) is not possible:

> [image: locked]

For posts that have [historical lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts) voting button are not even visible:

> [image: historical lock]

What is the reason to display voting buttons for regular locked posts if voting is not possible at all, why no to hide it as done for historical locked posts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ordinary lock is temporary, usually when there is a dispute in comments, or edit war. It does not mean the question is off topic, or that the post should be deleted. Even very good questions/answers can be locked that way. So having the voting buttons in place mean, in my opinion, that you can vote, in theory, just not now in the current state of the post. It is also consistent with deleted posts, where you can also see the voting buttons and click them.

Historical lock, on the other hand, is a totally different thing. It's is a powerful version of the ordinary lock, and is put on questions which are **off topic for the site and would otherwise be deleted**. Hence, it's is a permanent lock which will never be removed, so hiding the vote arrows there is clear sign for this.

Comment: I don't think that first post from my question has *temporary* lock. This lock is permanent also like historical.

Comment: It is temporary lock by design, in special cases where the post is likely to have lots of bad comments, the moderators sometimes just put it without expire time, but IMO it's wrong. Flagged that question asking to remove the lock.

Comment: Should other ordinary locked questions be flaged to remove the lock if lock was added too long time ago?

Comment: @alexolut depends, one exception is the ZALGO answer on SO which will get tons of flags, daily... probably other examples on SO, but generally speaking yes, if you see lock for over a year and no real reason to keep it, flag asking to remove it.

Comment: This question, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th, has voting arrows but I cannot upvote it. Why? The post is not off-topic.

Comment: @Mari-LouA it has ordinary lock which means we see the voting arrows but can't vote. It is locked to prevent flood of non constructive comments. For questions with the historical lock, there are no vote arrows at all and we can't even flag them.

Comment: I understand *why* it was locked, but not why we cast our votes. You can vote on something w/o editing/vandalising a post.

Comment: @Mari-LouA that's how locking works for SE: it prevents all actions on the post, including voting. You can start feature request asking to change that behavior. :-)