# Why are there "greater-than-signs (>)" in locked post vote-totals tooltips?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, tooltips

Wherever I go, if I click on the vote totals tooltip on a locked question or answer that has historical significance, there is always a `>` present just before the description.
This screenshot:

[image]

Confirms that.  This screenshot:

[image]

Is of a post that is not locked.  Why is this behavior only present in locked post vote-totals tooltips?  Why is it present at all?

---

### An example post:

[Jon Skeet Facts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts); it has a historical lock.  Hover over or click on the vote-totals tooltips on the answers as well as the question.

It also happens when reviewing VLQ posts  that are *not* locked:

[image]

Comment: Do you have an example question?

Comment: @KodosJohnson This [gets you started](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=locked%3a1%20is%3aquestion%20migrated%3a0%20duplicate%3a0)

Comment: That's a bug, most likely. It surely shouldn't be there.

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask Thanks for retagging then.

Comment: If I had to guess I would say the arrow is used as the border of the triangle attached to the left side of the tooltip. Note that there is a border on the triangle for the tooltip on the non-locked question but there is no border on the triangle for the tooltip on the locked question. It's probably supposed to be flipped horizontally to serve that purpose but it's broken.

Comment: @AdamLear It’s because of the `<div class="grid--cell ta-center fc-black-500">` that the vote count and the label “votes” is in. It has a `text-align: center;` rule which affects the pseudo elements comprising the little arrow. Applying `display: block;` to both `::before` and `::after` of the `<div class="s-popover--arrow">` fixes it, because it makes them not behave as inline boxes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was fixed in the most recent build.  Just an interaction between some old styling patterns, and some new ones.

Funnily enough, you can't really see it in dark mode - and a decent number of us test in dark mode to make sure we don't accidentally break it.

Comment: > thanks for the quick fix! :)