# Accepted answer icon is out of alignment on highly scored answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, answers, accepted-answer

Over at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com), there is a highly-scored, accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-processing-an-unsorted-array/11227902#11227902) with its accepted icon well out of alignment:

[image]

Also [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342031/thank-you-shog9/342059#342059) answer, here on Meta:

[image]

Can we fix the alignment of the checkmarks to match that of the timeline, voting, and occasionally bounty icons?  It should look like this:

[image]

The `text-align` is currently set to `left`; it needs to be set to `center`.

Comment: Another example, here on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342059/622284

Comment: @Spevacus You're right, thanks for a non SO example.

Comment: Hey look at that. I'll get this fixed right away.

Comment: It appears to be fixed now; click on the above link.

Comment: Looks like a regression from fixing [Why are there "greater-than-signs (>)" in locked post vote-totals tooltips?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354707/289905). The “votes” label is still not centered.