# How does reputation cap actually work?

Tags: support, daily-reputation-limit

I've looked around a fair bit on how the reputation system works, but I still can't understand how the situation I just ran into is possible:

http://img197.imageshack.us/img197/281/tmpkxc.png

I suppose I hit the cap, since I got 34 in rep out of 4 up-votes, but since accepted answers are "ignored"/"immune" against the cap, I should be able to reach 200+3*15 = 245 before capping, no?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8086/how-to-get-over-200-reputation-points-every-day

Comment: Still don't get it :( I must have hit the limit at what point? And got what afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you deleted an answer with 1 upvote today?

Comment: Hmm. that's possible... Still not clear to me how that comes into the picture? (but it's impressive that you could draw that conclusion).

Comment: @aioobe, deleted answers are not shown on the list, and which cause 235 and you have a downvote rep-cap give you +2 back, so its became 237