# How are these points with limit of 200 per day possible

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation, statistics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)
> [How to get over 200 reputation points every day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8086/how-to-get-over-200-reputation-points-every-day)

Check out these [stats](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/quarter/stackoverflow/2011-07-01?sort=totalreputation).

If there is a limit of 200 points per day (excluding bounty) how could these top 5 or even top ten people got score of over quarter million in about two years?
Who wrote this calculation code? It seems like the typical thing of business wanting one thing, developers thinking of another, and testers testing something else altogether; every one is a winner.

Comment: It's generally a good idea to understand how the system is meant to work before casting aspersions about the quality of the code/tests.

Comment: `Seems like typical thing of business wanting one thing, developers thinking of another and testers testing something else altogether; every one is a winner.` - say what?

Comment: @Sathya the OP thought it's a bug in the Leagues calculation, or members gaming the system.. without enough information it's easy to fall into such pits. :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet I have great respect for you for many other e.g BalusC you guys deserve to be there are a great inspiration but I enjoy stirring up every one here at MSO thats why I came up with this instead of asking a straight question.

Comment: @Sathya I recommend you visit http://english.stackexchange.com/ more often.'Say what' is not proper question .

Comment: @JavaKaBaby [it's not meant to be](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=say%20what)

Comment: [Say what again !!!!](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=say%20what%20again) by the way you do not need you wear sunglasses indoor

Answer (score 9):

Please read the faq:

https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day. Please note that votes for posts marked “community wiki” do not generate any reputation, while accepted answers and bounty awards are not subject to the daily reputation limit.

Comment: O mate last thing I expected was to see Jeff answering it :) my accusation is not real mate just wanted to know and stir ever body.Question was legit i.e how points work and how come these guys have so many with 200 CAP but the whole code and testing thing I made up.

Comment: @Java Ka Baby: Accusing the development team of following sloppy practices and trying to "stir everybody up" are generally considered poor form around here.  Don't take this the wrong way, I understand that your comments are all in good fun.  But please understand also that one's subtle intentions are not always conveyed through a text-only medium.  Objectively interpreted, such comments very easily come off as accusations.

Comment: @David point taken +1

Answer (score 5):

The 200 points cap is just for points from **upvotes** - accepted answer does not count towards this limit.

See this question for more details:
[How to get over 200 reputation points every day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8086/how-to-get-over-200-reputation-points-every-day)