# How do I go about obtaining 20 reputation points in one day?

Tags: discussion, badges, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [6 simple tips to get Stack Overflow reputation fast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/6-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast)
>   [What’s the best way to boost my Stack Overflow score?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50148/whats-the-best-way-to-boost-my-stack-overflow-score)

How do I go about obtaining 20 reputation points in one day?

I am a newbie to stack overflow(and to coding in general), so I was wondering if any of you could give me some tips and ideas on how to get these points! Thanks!

Comment: Start by reading the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation

Comment: 20? Do you mean 200?

Comment: Related: [What's the best way to boost my Stack Overflow score?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50148/whats-the-best-way-to-boost-my-stack-overflow-score) and [How to get over 200 reputation points every day?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8086/how-to-get-over-200-reputation-points-every-day)

Answer (score 1):

Answer questions; [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) are the guidelines on how to answer well.