# How much max reputation one can earn per day

Tags: discussion, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get over 200 reputation points every day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8086/how-to-get-over-200-reputation-points-every-day)

I was thinking how much max reputation one can earn per day is 200.
I have seen this  url https://stackoverflow.com/users/1679863/rohit-jain

He has got 23k in 3 months . how can he get that

Comment: By not walking away from the computer very often. Bounties and acceptance bonuses aren't blocked by the reputation cap. That might be a new record.

Comment: As another part of the mystery.... 110 days means they're only 1000-odd above the rep-cap level, which is pretty reasonable to get from accepted answers, bounties, etc.

Answer (score 10):

Accepted answers and bounties can cause it to go over 200 in a day.

Comment: What time is used to count this day? UTC time or?

Comment: @herohuyongtao, UTC.