# Flaggable or not?

Tags: bug, comments, flags

I went on a locked post like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8086/how-to-get-over-200-reputation-points-every-day) one.
I tried to upvote one of the comments, and this error message popped up.
[image: pic1]
I tried flagging one comment.
[image: pic2]
It actually worked! I flagged it!
I think you should disable flagging, or change the error message.

PS: Sorry mods, please ignore this useless flag. I was just testing.